# how does Chrome manages references to javascript constructor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Please consider this code :

```
function A() {
    console.log("first");
}

var f = A;

function A() {
    console.log("second");
}

var g = A;

f();
g();
```

It outputs "first", "second" in firebug, which is what I thought it should do.
But it outputs "second", "second", in Chrome's console, or in firefox (when executing from a file, not in firebug).
Why should the reference kept in 'f' be changed I do the second "function A() {" ??

It seems like hoisting is the problem (see apsillers' answer bellow). But then, why does this example work correctly (I mean output first-second) :

```
var A = function A() {
    console.log("first");
}

var f = A;

A = function A() {
    console.log("second");
}

var g = A;

f();
g();
```

The fact that I used "A = ..." in the second function declaration blocks the hoisting of this function ?

Comment: I see "`second`", "`second`" in Firefox 21.

Comment: yes my mistake, it's in firebug's console on firefox

Comment: When you say you execute it in Firebug, are you executing it as a single command, or as multiple commands?

Comment: This is a good question, but it's a question about Firebug, not a question about Chrome (since Chrome is exhibiting the correct behavior, just like any other browser would).

Comment: possible duplicate of [firebug console not doing hoisting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693526/firebug-console-not-doing-hoisting)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function declarations are [hoisted to the top of their scope](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/), so your code is interpreted like so:

```
function A() {
    console.log("first");
}

// overwrite previous A
function A() {
    console.log("second");
}

// variable declarations are hoisted as well
// (not directly related to your problem here, but worth noting)
var f;
var g;

f = A;
g = A;

f();
g();
```

which produces the output of `second`, `second` in any modern browser.

In your second example, with `var A = ...`, you're now using function *expressions*, rather than function *declarations*. Function expressions are *not* hoisted.

**Firebug weirdness**

It appears that -- for some reason -- Firebug doesn't correctly perform function declaration hoisting:

```
console.log(bar);  // this line incorrectly produces a ReferenceError!

function bar() { }
```

This code snippet *should* log `function bar() { }`. It does so in any proper browser environment, but not Firebug.

**EDIT**:

The reason for the Firebug behavior is that Firebug code runs inside of a block, and [function declarations are not valid in blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8871984/710446). However, browsers will still handle them in non-strict mode, but *how* they handle them differs. Firefox treats them as unhoisted (while IE and Chrome do hoist them, as it happens).

Comment: Actually `var g` comes before `f = A`.

Comment: Right, I'll make the non-function hoisting behavior explicit as well.

Comment: good answer, but then, why does this print "first", "second" correctly : var A = function A() [...] A = function A() ?? (I edited my question with the complete new code)

Comment: ok actually your link contains the explanation (see the conclusion, function expression versus function declaration). thanks !