# If functions in JS are first-class, what allows them to be called before they are defined?

Tags: javascript, syntax, functional-programming, first-class-functions

Don't first class functions mean that they behave as variables?  Clearly they don't behave exactly like variables though, since this:

```
console.log(foo);
var foo = 'bar';
```

...doesn't work, whereas this:

```
console.log(foo());
function foo() {
 return('bar');
}
```

...does.

That said, this:

```
console.log(foo());
var foo = function() { return 'bar'; };
```

doesn't work, which is more consistent.

What gives?

Comment: _"Doesn't first class functions mean that they behave as variables?"_ - No, that's not what "first class" means. You need to understand the difference between a "variable" and a "value", and that (in JS) the "value" may be a primitive (e.g., a number) or a reference to an object - and functions are a type of object. It may help to hover your mouse over the "first-class-functions" tag and read the description that pops up...

Comment: That's essentially, AFAIK, the definition of a variable...

Comment: @wwaawaw: Not really.  A variable is simply *named storage*.  Values are the things that can be stored in variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you don't compare the same thing. In your example - you compare **function declaration** `function foo()...` with **variable declaration and assignment** in `var foo = 'bar';`

A more correct comparison would be of:

```
console.log(foo);
var foo = 'bar';
```

with

```
console.log(foo());
var foo = function() {
 return 'bar';
}
```

The **functional declaration** is interpreted differently due to the way **hoisting** works. Hoisting moves all **declarations** to the top of the closest scope, **while leaving assignments** in their place.

Function declaration is special in that sense, since it's both declaration and expression/assignment in one statement and thus hoisted together.

As an example: you can look at expressions like:

```
console.log(foo);
var foo = 'bar';
```

as this:

```
var foo;
console.log(foo); //prints undefined
foo = 'bar';
```

and

```
console.log(foo());
var foo = function() {
 return 'bar';
}
```

as this:

```
var foo;
console.log(foo());
foo = function() {
 return 'bar';
}
```

Comment: Seems like coffeescript makes this really explicit and takes it out from behind the scenes.

Comment: So then `console.log(foo()); function foo(){return 'bar';}` would be the equivalent of `var foo = function(){return 'bar';}; console.log(foo());`, and both would print `bar`, correct?

Comment: Obviously I meant semantically equivalent.  Accepted, BtW.  Thank you for actually explaining what's really going on instead of just how to use it.  Your knowledge of the language doesn't improve at all without answers being linked to the broader linguistic concepts as yours is.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 18):

What you're experiencing is called hoisting. When using a **function declaration** like:

```
function foo() {}
```

`foo` will be moved to the top of the closest scope (function).

On the other hand when you use a **function expression** or **function assignment** like:

```
var foo = function() {}
```

the variable `foo` will be moved to the top but the assignment will occur when is needed.

**[Learn more](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)**

Comment: Is _scope_ actually fully synonymous with _function_?

Comment: In JavaScript yes, scopes are functions, there is no block scope.

Comment: @elclanrs which is so sad in cases like `for(var i...)`

Comment: Function declarations in blocks are actually not officially supported in current JavaScript. ES6 on the other hand will have block scope, and block-scoped function declarations.

Comment: @adlwalrus Nope, because there is a **global scope** in addition to function local scope.

Answer (score 6):

Function declarations are automatically bumped to top of the scope in JS

```
console.log(foo());
function foo() {
 return('bar');
}
```

is actually interpreted as

```
function foo() {
 return('bar');
}
console.log(foo());
```

the second bit of code is working that way, because foo is variable, not a function (it just happens to have an anonymous function as a value). Variables are also bumped to top, so

```
console.log(foo());
var foo = function() { return 'bar'; };
```

becomes

```
var foo; //empty variable
console.log(foo()); //undefined
foo = function() { return 'bar'; }; //creates a function without name and assigns it to foo
```

Comment: Is that to say that
```
function foo(){ return 'bar'; }
```

doesn't also create a variable named foo with the function `function(){return 'bar';}` as its value?

Comment: @adlwalrus it creates the variable, but the value is `function foo(){return 'bar';}` (named function, not anonymous).

Comment: So functions have "names" in addition to those of the variables that hold them as their values?

Comment: @adlwalrus yes. try this: `var foo = function bar(){}; console.log(foo);` But be aware that `bar` is only function name (what does it mean I'm not sure exactly myself) and not a reference to it, so you can't call it by doing `bar()`. And assigning (even named function) is not the same as declaring a function. Hoisting (bumping to top of the scope) only works for declarations, assignment will stay in place.

Comment: Thanks man, great answer, and very interesting.  Grounds for a new question, I'd say.

Answer (score 4):

Function declaration and variable declaration will always be moved to the top of their  scope.

```
console.log(foo());
function foo() {
   return 'bar';
}
```

is interpreted as:

```
function foo() {
   return 'bar';
}
console.log(foo());
```

---

```
console.log(foo());
var foo = function () {
   return 'bar';
};
```

is interpreted as:

```
var foo;
console.log(foo());
foo = function () {
   return 'bar';
};
```

Comment: Oh, I see.  Actually the most complete answer here.  Accepted.

Comment: Actually I take the acceptance back because ZenMaster's seems more thorough.  Still great answer though.