# How to handle async functions in nodejs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, first-class-functions

I have been learning nodejs, and one thing that continues to boggle my mind is async programming that nodejs is built on. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but despite all my research I can't wrap my mind around how I should adapt to it coming from synchronous programming background. I would really appreciate if someone gave me a simple async example based on the below structure, given you want to call func2 from anywhere.

```
function1(){
  var obj = function2();
  console.log(obj); //"undefined".
}

function2(){
  //do stuff with DB and get obj
  console.log(obj); //logs obj.
  return obj;
}
```

The problem I stumbled upon is that obj prints as undefined in func1, while func2 has no problems with it. When I nested the functions within each other it worked, leading me to believe that due to async nature of nodejs it proceeded to log in func1 before func2 was finished. Am I wrong with my assumptions?

What I struggle with in the above example, is how would I code the functions instead of nesting them within each other, so I can call func2 from several different functions at once. I've looked into callbacks but couldn't understand the examples given in various answers with a function inside a function.

Comment: This is really a JavaScript question, not exclusive to nodejs.

Comment: Really? I thought only nodejs was asynchronous, not JS as whole. Granted, I've only worked with JS in HTML, maybe that's where my confusion comes from..

Comment: AJAX - *Asynchronous* JavaScript And XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define functions (i.e. the callbacks) within functions.

```
1  function function1(){
2    function2(function(obj) {
3      console.log(obj); //logs obj.
     });
   }

4  function function2(callbackFn){
     //do stuff with DB and get obj
     console.log(obj); //logs obj.
5    callbackFn(obj);
   }
```

`function2` can be called from many places at once, not just `function1`.

If you can be more specific about what you don't understand, then you might get a better answer.

---

*Functions are values, just like numbers, strings and objects.*

This is the core fundamental of functional programming, and probably the thing you haven't grasped. In JavaScript, as in a number of languages, functions are not special*. This is different to languages like C or Java, where functions/methods are different to the usual values you deal with in your code.

```
2; // Here is a number
var a = 2; // I can assign it to a variable
console.log(2); // I can pass it as a function argument

function() {} // Here is a function
var a = function() {}; // I can assign it to a variable
console.log(function() {}); // I can pass it as a function argument

function jim() {} // This function's name is jim
var a = jim; // I can assign it to a variable
console.log(jim); // I can pass it as a function argument

(function() {})(); // I can call a function without giving it any names
jim(); // I can call a named function
a(); // I can call a function via a variable
jim.call(this, arg1); // Or I can get complicated
```

So, we can declare functions and pass them around, separately to calling them. Now, what about the code we started with.

1. Declare a new function called `function1` that takes no arguments
2. When `function1` is called, call `function2` with a single argument, a new nameless function that takes an `obj` argument
3. When the anonymous function is called, call `console.log` with the value passed for `obj`
4. Declare a new function called `function2` that takes a single argument `callbackFn`
5. Call the value passed for `callbackFn` with a single argument, the `obj` we got from somewhere

So the declaration order is 1, 4, 2; and the execution order is 2, 5, 3.

*OK, they're a little special. Their definitions are [hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12274014/476716), you can execute the code they represent, and their declarations create [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/476716) and [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/476716). But those are all questions for another time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for elaborating! The part I don't understand about it is sending the function(obj) as an argument when calling function2, how it returns the value to function1 (the callbackFn(obj) line). I can't really grasp logic of what is happening there.

Comment: It doesnt return the value to function1,it execute the function given as an argument of function2. function1 just cant know when callbackFn will be executed. It called Continuation Passing,it is basically like an Async GOTO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to break it down OrangeDog. I think I got it, that line 2 passes a nameless function to function2 which the function2 executes after it's done with the primary task of getting obj. That was the confusing part for me, thanks!