# Functions are not being assigned to another function's prototype in Chrome

Tags: javascript, prototype, function-prototypes

The following code works properly in Firefox but not in Chrome?
If you comment out line 15 to prevent the error on line 7 (cannot find this.update()), the code continues to execute properly. I cannot see why the first set of definitions is different to the first.

```
if (typeof RegionUpdater == "undefined") {
    function RegionUpdater(param1, param2, param3) {
        this.paramA = param1;
        this.paramB = param2;
        this.paramC = param3;

        this.update();
    }

    RegionUpdater.prototype.update = function() {
        alert("hi there");
    };
}

var ru = new RegionUpdater("1", 2, "3");

function LolUpdater(param1, param2, param3) {
    this.paramA = param1;
    this.paramB = param2;
    this.paramC = param3;

    this.update();
}

LolUpdater.prototype.update = function() {
    alert("hi there");
};

var lu = new LolUpdater(1, 2, 3);
```

I've got a jsfiddle setup here: http://jsfiddle.net/XhbZ8/2/

EDIT: The only idea I've been able to come up with is that Chrome has some sort of speculative execution going on, but the fact that I also get the same problem in IE8 makes me less inclined to believe that's the case.

Comment: This is most likely a hoisting issue, this works http://jsfiddle.net/XhbZ8/3/

Comment: It doesn't work. You only see the 2nd alert box, not the first. Could you please explain what a hoisting issue is?

Comment: See if my answer helps. Nor sure if that's the problem tho...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check [Why are function declarations handled differently in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871974/why-are-function-declarations-handled-differently-in-different-browsers)

This seems like a hoisting issue. The `if` statement gets ignored because this is what happens:

```
if (typeof RegionUpdater === 'undefined') {
  function RegionUpdater() {}
}
```

The above will be interpreted in the following because functions get hoisted (moved to) the top of the closest scope (function), in this case the scope is the global object.

```
function RegionUpdater() {}
if (typeof RegionUpdater === 'undefined') {
  // won't run since RegionUpdater is already defined
}
```

You could workaround it like this:

```
var RegionUpdater = RegionUpdater || function RegionUpdater(){

};
```

**Edit:** Like Mics said, using a function expression should work:

```
if (typeof RegionUpdater === 'undefined') {
  var RegionUpdater = function RegionUpdater(){};
  ...
}
```

Because this is how it happens:

```
var RegionUpdater;
if (typeof RegionUpdater === 'undefined') {
  RegionUpdater = function RegionUpdater(){};
  ...
}
```

Comment: Or using *function expression* and *assignment* instead of *declaration* like this: `var RegionUpdater = function () { ... }`

Comment: The fourth code sample, suggested by Mics, is the answer to my problem. Thank you both so very very much.