# Does strict mode prohibit statement level function declarations?

Tags: javascript, strict

```
"use strict";

if (true) {
  function foo() {
  }
}
```

In PhpStorm this code shows an error:

> Function statement not at top level of a program or function is prohibited

However, Chrome happily executes it, even in the debugger and without any console output.

Now is it prohibited or not?

Comment: It shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Chrome still keep silent when using functions inside blocks in “strict mode”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756010/why-chrome-still-keep-silent-when-using-functions-inside-blocks-in-strict-mode)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, in ES5 they are prohibited (and in strict mode, all implementations throw). See also [Kangax' great article](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks) for function statements in sloppy mode.

However, in ES6 they are block-level function declarations with new semantics. See also [What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31419897/1048572). This seems to be what Chrome implements here; `foo` is not available outside of the `if` block.

Comment: So my Chrome implements the latest spec while my PhpStorm is behind? My JS language level is set to `JSX Harmony`.

Comment: @AndreKR: That's likely. I'm not familiar with PhpStorm or "JSX Harmony", but given that ES Harmony is an ongoing process this seems to be dubious :-) Are you using ES6 yet?

Comment: I'm not using it but while investigating this I changed the language level. The error shows up with language level set to "ECMAScript 6", too.