# Why does redeclaring a function identifier within a try block throw a SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

The following lines of JavaScript

```
try {
    function _free() {}
    var _free = 1;
} finally { }
```

result in the following error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '_free' has already been declared
```

However, the following two blocks of JavaScript code don't:

1. Without the `try` block scope:

   ```
   function _free() {}
   var _free = 1;
   ```
2. Within a `function` scope:

   ```
   function a() {
       function _free() {}
       var _free = 1;
   }
   ```

But why?

(Testing environment: Chromium 61.0.3126.0)

Comment: Did you use `strict mode` somewhere?

Comment: @Jai Nothing to do with strict mode, also it's called `use strict` :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Ahh... That's correct. i meant the same.

Comment: @Jai I didn't. :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because [block-scoped function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31861239/1048572) are a new ES6 feature and were made safe (i.e. throw an error on name collisions, similar to `let` and `const`), but the other cases (which are programmer mistakes regardless) needed to stay backwards compatible and silently overwrite the function.

Comment: I wonder does this happen in other browsers and older browsers that don't ES6

Comment: @Bergi would this be due to `strict mode`. May be somewhere OP used it.

Comment: I tested it in IE nothing happens. But firefox and other new browsers have it

Comment: @user93 Treatment of block-level function declarations [was very inconsistent](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks) before ES6

Comment: @user93 IE implements the least amount of ES6 features out of all the major browsers.

Comment: @user93—there is history to "block scoped function declarations", best to just not use them. Use function expressions if you want to conditionally create functions.

Comment: @Jai No, [strict mode doesn't really affect this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461615/1048572)

Comment: Thanks! Though the code including these redeclaring statements are generated by emscripten and it seems a little outdated...:/

Answer (score 5):

To expand on [Bergis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44897244/5460631), there is a difference in how the code is interpreted in ES5 and ES6 since block-scoped function declarations were added.

Input:

```
function test() {
    try {
        function _free() { }
        var _free = 1;
    } finally { }
}
```

Since ES5 does not support block-level functions, `_free` is [hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28246589/5460631) to the parent function:

```
function test() {
    var _free = function _free() { }
    try {
        var _free = 1;
    } finally { }
}
```

In ES6, the function is declared at block-level, and semantically equal to a `let`/`const` declaration:

```
function test() {
    try {
        let _free = function _free() { }
        var _free = 1;
    } finally { }
}
```

This throws an error because `var _free` tries to *declare* a variable which is already declared.
For example, this throws in ES6 as well:

```
let _free;
var _free = 1;    // SyntaxError: Indentifier '_free' has already been declared
```

While this is fine:

```
var _free;
var _free = 1;    // No SyntaxError
```

Setting the value of the *already declared* identifier is fine:

```
let _free;
_free = 1;
```

Therefore, to set the *declared* identifier `_free` to 1, you need to skip the second *declaration*:

```
try {
    function _free() { }
    _free = 1;
} finally { }
```

Comment: "*Since ES5 does not support block-level functions, _free is hoisted to the parent function*" doesn't really make sense. It did **not support them**, so the code simply was a syntax error. Nothing got hoisted.

Comment: An ES6 function declaration isn't completely semantically equivalent to `let`/`const`, as it is still hoisted.