# javascript- Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier * has already been declared

Tags: javascript, scope, var, hoisting

```
console.log(a) //output:ƒ a(){}
var a = 1;
function a(){};
var a = 10;
console.log(a) //output:10
```

====================

```
var a = 1;
if(true){
  function a(){};
  var a = 10;
}
console.log(a) // this code throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
```

both above code snippets are same except the if block.why does the latter throws error when its permissible in javascript to delcare same variable twice in the same scope with var as below

```
 function a(){};
 var a = 10; //no error
```

Also for a slightly different scenario after removing var from `var a = 10 in the above code ,then it works fine but output is surprising

```
 var a = 1;
 if(true) {
   function a(){};
   a = 10;
 }
 console.log(a) //output:ƒ a(){}
```

I am surprised to see this output as I am expecting 10 ..because two variables declared inside the if block refer to the same variable declared above as javascript var doesnt respect block scope but functional scope...so why not the output for above should be 10?
where as the below code outputs 10 as i expected when replaced the function definition with function expression.

```
  var a = 1;
  if(true) {
    var a = function(){ console.log() }
    a = 10;
  }
  console.log(a) //output:10
```

Comment: Well, function declarations inside `if` blocks were invalid in ES5, so using them will have [ES6 semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461615/1048572) with stricter rules about duplicate declarations.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Why does redeclaring a function identifier within a try block throw a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44897189/1048572)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> This is surprising as javascript `var` doesn't respect block scope but functional scope...

Sure, but you didn't use `var` for the declaration of `a` in the block scope. You used a function declaration, which [*does* respect block scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461615/1048572) (otherwise it would be [completely invalid code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24573752/1048572), as in ES5 strict mode).

> It's permissible in javascript to declare same variable twice in the same scope with `var` as below

Same applies here. The `function` declaration in the block uses ES6 declaration semantics (like `let` or `const`), which does not allow redeclarations.

Answer (score 15):

**Case 1**

```
console.log(a) //output:ƒ a(){}
var a = 1;
function a(){};
var a = 10;
console.log(a) //output:10
```

Will be rendered as

```
var a;
a = function(){}; // now a holds the value as a function
console.log(a); // output : f a(){}
a = 1; // a is a var that holds value 1
a = 10; // a is a var that holds value 10
console.log(a); // output : 10
```

**Case 2**

```
var a = 1;
if(true){
   function a(){};
   var a = 10;
}
console.log(a)
```

Will be rendered as

```
var a;
a = 1;
if(true) {
    a = function() {};
    let a; // The function declaration in the block uses ES6 declaration semantics (like let or const), which does not allow re-declarations.
    var a; // throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
    a = 10;
}
console.log(a);
```

**Case 3**

```
var a = 1;
if(true){
    function a(){};
    a = 10;
 }
console.log(a)
```

Will be rendered as

```
var a;
a = 1;
if(true) {
    a = function() {};
    let a;
    a = 10;
}
console.log(a); // output : f a(){}
```

**Case 4**

```
var a = 1;
if(true){
    var a= function(){console.log()}
    a = 10;
}
console.log(a)
```

Will be rendered as

```
var a;
a = 1;
if(true) {
    a = function(){console.log()}
    a = 10;
}
console.log(a) // output:10
```

**Case 5**

```
var a = 1;
if(true){
    function a(){};
    a = 10;
    console.log(a) 
}
console.log(a)
```

Will be rendered as

```
var a;
a = 1;
if(true){
    a = function() {};
    let a;
    a = 10;
    console.log(a); // output:10
}
console.log(a); // output : f a(){}
```

Comment: More like `let a` in case 3.

Comment: @Bergi - Thank you. I have taken reference from your answer while posting my understanding. Hope it is okay with you. If not, I will be happy to remove my answser.

Comment: @PrashantTapase - Thank you. I have updated my answer for better understanding and you can now see the behavior with the false statements as well.

Comment: @nikhilagw It's fine :-)

Comment: @nikhilagw  great..its very clear and Thanks for the answer with detailed scenarios ...could you  also please mention how this piece of code is rendered ...if(true) {
    function b(){}
} ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am asking this because when i execute this code in chrome console  ..console.log(b); //output:undefined
if(true) {
    function b(){}
}
console.log(b); //output:ƒ b(){}  so I am doubtful if function declarations  are treated like let/const as b is available outside the block as well

Comment: @venkata - In your case it will be like this. `var b; console.log(b); if(true) { b = function(){}} console.log(b);` Because of this the first console gives undefined and the second gives the function. The declarations are hoisted to parent function scope, however, the value is set in the scope only. Any function definition in the block, basically ends up blocking the variable name in that block just like let and const do, however, the association of the function is always with the parent function scope. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Its very clear now.Thanks a lot nikhilagw.Thanks @Bergi

Comment: @venkata, nikhilagw: the [details of sloppy mode block scope function declarations in browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461615/1048572) are just weird. You should use strict mode and ignore what you just saw :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Agreed. Makes sense. :)

Answer (score 5):

The simple solution to this is to use IIFE

```
(function() {
var sahil = {
  checkThis: function() {
    console.log(this);

    function checkOther() {
      console.log(this);
    }
    checkOther(); // checkThis() function called in "global context", will
                  // return "this" as "window"
  }
};
var moo = sahil.checkThis;
moo(); // moo() function called in "global context", will return "this" as "window" })();
```