# Why can't I declare functions or variables at the block statement?

Tags: javascript, function

In the function, running normally, this displays "Hello world":

```
function fn () {
    function b1 () {}
    var b1 = 'Hello world';
    console.log(b1);
}
fn();
```

At the block statement, get an error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'b1' has already been declared**

```
function fn () {
     if (true) {
         function b1 () {};
         var b1 = 'Hello world';
         console.log(b1);
    }
}
fn();
```

So there is clearly something "special" about a block statement with respect to function declarations. why?

Comment: does this answer your question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774769/javascript-uncaught-syntaxerror-identifier-has-already-been-declared