# JS IIFE breaks YouTube Tracking

Tags: javascript, iife, event-tracking

I'm confused as to why putting my YouTube tracking code into an IIFE stops it working.

My understanding was that IIFEs run instantly, so why is there a difference between including a script with just bare js vs an IFEE?

Here's my plain JS, which works correctlly:

```
if ( 0 < ga_options.youtube.length ) {
    var tag = document.createElement( 'script' );
    tag.src = '//www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' )[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore( tag, firstScriptTag );

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        scroll_events.register_youtube_videos();
    }
}
```

However, when I wrap it in an IIFE, like below, it no longer works (no tracking events are fired). I am trying to use an IIFE as part of a restructuring of existing code into self-contained units.

Please could someone explain what I am doing wrong? I have considered scope and tried using `var tag` and `var firstScriptTag` outside of the IIFE, but still no success.

```
gaEventsVideoTracking = (function(){

    window.console.log( "why no youtube tracking?" );
        if ( 0 < ga_options.youtube.length ) {
            tag = document.createElement( 'script' );
            tag.src = '//www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
            firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' )[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore( tag, firstScriptTag );

            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                scroll_events.register_youtube_videos();
            }
        }
})();
```

Comment: I've a feeling `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` wants to be on your global.   So you could maybe do -> `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {}` instead.

Comment: Fixed syntax with missing brace. Still broken.

Comment: @Keith Indeed. [It really never should have worked before, though](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31861239/1048572).

Comment: You mean version 1,  outside of the IIFE? The syntax error was due to pasting issues.

Comment: @Keith That worked just fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` gets called by the script loaded from YouTube's servers.

Since you are using a function declaration to define it, it is **locally** scoped to the IIFE. This means it is not a global and thus not available for YouTube's script to call.

You can explicitly make it a global.

Add `var onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;` at line one (**outside** the IIFE) and then put `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady =` in front of the function declaration to make it a function expression and assign it to the global variable.

Comment: Of course there's not really any reason to place the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` declaration inside the IIFE in the first place.

Comment: @Bergi — Or use an IIFE at all since all the other variables created inside it are implicit globals.