# Function declarations cannot be nested within non-function blocks

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am reading about Function Declarations vs. Function Expressions, and I cannot figure out the meaning of following statement:

> Function Declarations occur as standalone constructs and cannot be
>   nested within non-function blocks.

Someone please to explain with an exemple what does the author means, precisely by: "...cannot be nested within non-function blocks".

Link is: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: Further reading: [*What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know the author meant it was physically impossible or more of it shouldn't be done. From my understanding what the author was saying is that this:

```
var y = true;
if (y) {
    function example() {
    alert('hi');
    return true;
   }
}
```

Here the function is declared inside a conditional statement, which is fine since **x** is true, but if it were false that function would never be declared and when we do want to the call the **example** function nothing will happen because it was never declared. So it should be

```
function example() {
"use strict";
return true;
}
var y = true;
if (y) {
    example();
}
```

In the above code we still call the **example** function if the condition is met, however since example is defined outside the condition statement we can use it regardless of the conditional statement. [This Post has more information about it](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315012014/https://jslinterrors.com/function-statements-should-not-be-placed-in-blocks). Hopefully this is what you meant

Comment: yeaaah very persuading and true. Thanks for your quick idea. waiting for timer to expire +1

Comment: I also recommend reading @Pointy answer, it gives more insight about the  idea behind

Comment: @code, could you please update this dead link "This Post has more information about it" or replace it with the info you know. It would be helpful to understand the points you were referring, Thanks.

Comment: i still don't get the idea, would you please make a small effort to explain it a little bit more.

Answer (score 2):

Taken at face value, the statement:

> Function Declarations occur as standalone constructs and cannot be nested within non-function blocks.

is wrong. It's possible to put function declarations inside blocks, as examples in the article show. The reason that it's warned against is that the behaviour differs in different browsers. In most browsers (not certain versions of IE and Firefox), such functions are declared regardless of whether execution enters the block or not, e.g.:

```
if (false) {
  function foo(){}
}
```

*foo* is declared and available within the outer scope. This is exactly the same with variable declarations:

```
if (false) {
  var x = 3;
}
```

In the above, *x* is declared regardless of whether the block is executed or not. The assignment of the value, however, only occurs if the block is entered.

Back to functions. The reason function declarations in blocks is warned against is that firstly, it infers that the function is only created if the block is entered, which is incorrect for *most* browsers but not all. Secondly, and more importantly, it's because different browsers have different behaviour.

Some interesting reading:

- Richard Cornford: [FunctionExpressions and memory consumption](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/msg/6eb53953ca5ce6eb?hl=en)
- Kangax: [Function statements](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-statements)
- [*What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6)

Also note that function statements are [warned against in ES5 strict mode](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12) and may be introduced in some future version of ECMAScript.

Finally, this behaviour is addressed directly in ECMA-262 ed 6 in [Appendix B 3.3.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics) and [Appendix B 3.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-functiondeclarations-in-ifstatement-statement-clauses).

Comment: The good part is that no one can agree on a terminology: function statement, function declaration as a statement, function declaration within blocks, etc. and browsers can't agree on what to do about it. They even flip–flop in how they handle it between versions. Fun! ;-)

Comment: Thanks RobG for this big science and sharing. I will be reading your answer when have time and enough knowledge to understand it. I somehow agree with you since also the link I gave in OP contains ideas about browsers versions exceptions. Again thanks.

Comment: bro you should test the code in some browser to provide the reference,
I tested it in chrome 59.0, guess what if the condition is false, it gives me an exception

Comment: @Vick_Pk—perhaps you missed "**the behaviour differs in different browsers**" and "**…is incorrect for *most* browsers but not all**".

Answer (score 1):

I think it means you cannot define functions arbitrarily in the code, see below.

```
if true {
  function funName(){};
}
```

`funName` will not be a function in this case, it will cause an error.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: "*funName will not be a function*" is wrong. It will be a function in all browsers if the condition is true, and in some browsers even if it is false.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the humble `if` statement:

```
function whatever() {
  // ...
  if (something === somethingElse) {
    function aFunction() {
      // ...
    }

    // more code ...
  }

  aFunction(5, 6, 7);
```

Now, that code is weird. The function is declared inside the `if` block. But function declarations are hoisted! So what does that mean?

More weird: what if there's a *different* declaration for "aFunction" in the `else` clause?

A fundamental aspect of the weirdness from code like that is that function declarations are treated as if they occur at the top of the scope (that is, they're "hoisted"). For that reason, a function declaration inside some other sort of block is just inherently ambiguous and strange.

Note that function instantiation via function *expressions* are not weird, because those happen as part of running code, like object initialization expressions.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, this is it. convincing and well explained +1

Comment: "*But function declarations are hoisted*" but some browsers treat that pattern as a function statement, so not "hoisted" and the function is only created if the block is entered (e.g. IE 11).