# node.js blocking, non-blocking issue in for statement

Tags: node.js, express, blocking

How can I save all of the json into my mongoldb?
Strangely, only the first value is stored every time.
It might be blocking/non-blocking issue.

```
json = {
  ["name":"Karl","id":"azo0"],
  ["name":"Robert","id":"bdd10"],
  ["name":"Joan","id":"difj90"],
  ["name":"Hallyn","id":"fmak88"],
  ["name":"Michael","id":"vma91"]
};

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
  id = json[i].id;
  name = json[i].name;

  var ctx = {"id":id,"name":name};
  db.json_db.count(ctx).exec(function(err, count) {
    if(count < 1){
        var model = new User({
           "name":json[i].name,
           "id":json[i].id
        });
        model.save(function(){
            console.log("ok"+i);

        });
    }
  });
};
```

After inserting, all of datas are filled with ["name":"Karl","id":"azo0"]
To check out console.log("ok"+i), it prints always "ok0" not "ok1", "ok2", "ok3"... etc..

How can I prevent this issue?

Comment: FWIW: There is only **one** variable called `i` in the code: the same variable is accessed from each distinct closure. That said, I'd expect it to print "ok*5*" if it's truly asynchronous..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example ; also, ES-6 has `let`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892488/closures-versus-es6-let

Comment: Perfect!!!! Thank you user2864740 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase you're using [Async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) package, this is an best way to solve your problem...

```
  async.eachSeries(json, (item, done) => {
   let user = new User(
                     {
                        "name":json[i].name,
                         "id":json[i].id
                    },
                    (err, user) => {
                        if(err){
                           // handle err
                        }
                        return done();
                    }
                );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.exec()` tells me you're using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/). So your loop can rewritten as:

```
const json = [
  {name: "Karl", id: "azo0"},
  {name: "Robert", id: "bdd10"},
  {name: "Joan", id: "difj90"},
  {name: "Hallyn", id: "fmak88"},
  {name: "Michael", id: "vma91"}
];

for (const item of json) {
  const count = await db.json_db.count(item).exec()
  if (!count) {
    await new User(item).save()
  }
}
```

- Error handling omitted.
- See http://exploringjs.com/es2016-es2017/ch_async-functions.html

Comment: Thank you Mateo, Maybe that’s because everyone is basically used "var" instead of "let", "const". Thanks to you I can resolve my case :)