# How can I change the text content in html to a randomly generated value from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing an issue while coding for a small project. Basically, I am trying to make a flip box which, upon clicked by a user will show him if its any of the superhero mentioned in an array. Please take a look at this code pen to have an idea about it: https://codepen.io/zakero/pen/YmGmwK .

The code works perfectly when I am using alert(), as you can see in code pen. It randomizes every time a square is clicked. But I want the result to be displayed after it's clicked and flipped. I mean instead of "Back", I want it to be the random names of the superheroes. I have both tried .textContent and .innerHTML to change it but it doesn't seem to work This is the code I have tried:

Javascript:

```
function setupSquares() {
    for(var i = 0; i < frontSquare.length; i++) {
        frontSquare[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var randomNumber = frontSquare[i] = generateRandomNumbers(numbers);
            for(var j = 0; j < superhero.length; j++) {
                var index = superhero.indexOf(superhero[j]);
                if(randomNumber === index){
                    backSquare.textContent = superhero[j];
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

```js
var superhero = ["Ironman", "Superman", "Batman", "Spiderman", "Black Panther", "Hawkeye", "Hulk", "Captain America", "Thor", "Quicksilver", "Loki"];
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var frontSquare = document.querySelectorAll(".front");
var backSquare = document.querySelectorAll(".back");


init();

function init() {
  setupSquares();
}

function generateRandomNumbers(num) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length + 1);
  return random;
}

function setupSquares() {
  for (var i = 0; i < frontSquare.length; i++) {
    frontSquare[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var randomNumber = frontSquare[i] = generateRandomNumbers(numbers);
      for (var j = 0; j < superhero.length; j++) {
        var index = superhero.indexOf(superhero[j]);
        if (randomNumber === index) {
          alert(superhero[j]);
        }
      }

    });
  }
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body {
  background: #96CEB4;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #222;
}

#container {
  margin: 37px auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background: #96CEB4;
  height: 550px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 35px;
  margin: 1.66%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-radius: 50px;*/
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms;
  transition: all 600ms;
  z-index: 20;
}

.card div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFEEAD;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card .back {
  background: #FF6F69;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

label:hover .card {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
  transform: rotateX(20deg);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, .2);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

:checked+.card {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

label:hover :checked+.card {
  transform: rotateX(160deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(160deg);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

  <title>Flip Box</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <label class="square">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <div class="card">
          <div class="front">Front</div>
          <div class="back">Back</div>
      </div>
  </label>
    <label class="square">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <div class="card">
          <div class="front">Front</div>
          <div class="back">Back</div>
      </div>
  </label>
    <label class="square">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <div class="card">
          <div class="front">Front</div>
          <div class="back">Back</div>
      </div>
  </label>
    <label class="square">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <div class="card">
          <div class="front">Front</div>
          <div class="back">Back</div>
      </div>
  </label>
    <label class="square">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <div class="card">
          <div class="front">Front</div>
          <div class="back">Back</div>
      </div>
  </label>
    <label class="square">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <div class="card">
          <div class="front">Front</div>
          <div class="back">Back</div>
      </div>
  </label>
  </div>






  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `backSquare` is an array of dom elements, it holds every square, you need to choose which one the text will show up on. If you do `backSquare[0].textContent = superhero[j]` Then the back of the first card will change. Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound careful though! Since he's using `var` instead of `let` you don't have a closure over `i` in the loop

Comment: Thanks @SpeedOfRound for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get to the `.back` of the `.front` clicked using the following:

```
this.parentNode.querySelector('.back').innerText = superhero[j];
```

You see, for your case, you're missing a bunch of things. First of all `backSquare` is an array, so you have to access the element which you want to modify out of it. Instead of `backSquare.textContent = superhero[j];`, use `backSquare[i].innerText = superhero[j]` which allows you to access the same `i-th` `backSquare` as `frontSquare`. But careful, this would not work because you're using `var i = ...` in the loop variable and `var` doesn't create a closure over the loop. So to fix that, you could change `var` to `let`.

More about this here: [Closures versus ES6 Let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892488/closures-versus-es6-let)

Or, you could use `this` which refers to the current element being clicked. `this` gets populated by the current element being clicked with your `addEventListener` function.

More about `this`: https://codeburst.io/all-about-this-and-new-keywords-in-javascript-38039f71780c

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgbPEK

Comment: Hey it works perfectly now. Thank you. If you don't mind can you please explain where my issue was? Was it specificity of choosing .back class? Also can you please tell me what "this" keyword refers to?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this `this.closest('.card').querySelector('.back').textContent = superhero[j]`

Comment: Thank you so much. This works as well. Unfortunately I have chosen the answer above. But you answer is perfect too. Take care and happpy coding.

Comment: Thank you. Take care, be happy