# How to use javascript reduce function to calculate average of items meeting a specific condition?

Tags: javascript, reduce

So assume I have the following array of objects:

```
var arr = [
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.8"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.6"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "9.0"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.3"},
  {"name": "Tom",  "score": "7.9"}
];

var count = 0;
var avgScore = arr.reduce(function (sum,person) {
  if (person.name == "John") {
    count+=1;
    return sum + parseFloat(person.score);
  }
  return sum;
},0)/count);
```

Question: Is there a way way to calculate the average score for "John" without creating a global **count** variable.  Ideally, the count would be internal to the anonymous function in the arr.reduce.

Comment: I think this the best way to do it. As you said `count` would be wrapped inside a function so it won't be a problem! Plus you can accumulate both the sum and the count using an object inside reduce (`{sum: ..., count: ...}`)!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To avoid global variables, use a standard solution like [IIFEs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1048572) or [block scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33534485/1048572). However I guess you're looking for a way to avoid a mutable counter.

The simplest would be to drop all other persons beforehand:

```
var johns = arr.filter(function(person) {
  return person.name == "John";
});
var avgScore = johns.reduce(function (sum, person) {
  return sum + parseFloat(person.score);
}, 0) / johns.length;
```

But you can also use a `count` that is passed along with the sum in an object:

```
var stats = arr.reduce(function ({count, sum}, person) {
  return (person.name == "John")
    ? {count: count+1, sum: sum + parseFloat(person.score)}
    : {count, sum};
}, {count:0, sum:0})
var avgScore = stats.sum / stats.count);
```

<sub>(using ES6 object property shorthands and destructuring)</sub>

Comment: I think you meant `johns.reduce` not `àrr.reduce`!!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir indeed I did. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir Doing the filter and then the reduce iterates over the array twice. For large arrays, this would not be desirable.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @RandellD Use a lazy collections library :-)

Comment: @Bergi Even though there is a little more overhead with the object, I do like your 2nd solution.

Comment: Yeah, everything else requires mutation. Which might be faster than creating records, but for speed you'd just go for a simple loop instead of a functional `reduce`.

Comment: There are some other good solutions here, but I believe @Bergi does what I asked.

Answer (score 4):

You could return an object with the average in it, calculated on every loop with an update.

```js
var arr = [{ name: "John", score: "8.8" }, { name: "John", score: "8.6" }, { name: "John", score: "9.0" }, { name: "John", score: "8.3" }, { name: "Tom", score: "7.9" }],
    avgScore = arr.reduce(function (r, person) {
        if (person.name === "John") {
            r.sum += +person.score;
            r.avg = r.sum / ++r.count;
        }
        return r;
    }, { sum: 0, count: 0, avg: 0 }).avg;

console.log(avgScore);
```

A version with a closure and a direct return of the average.

```js
var arr = [{ name: "John", score: "8.8" }, { name: "John", score: "8.6" }, { name: "John", score: "9.0" }, { name: "John", score: "8.3" }, { name: "Tom", score: "7.9" }],
    avgScore = arr.reduce(function (sum, count) {
        return function (avg, person) {
            if (person.name === "John") {
                sum += +person.score;
                return sum / ++count;
            }
            return avg;
        };
    }(0, 0), 0);

console.log(avgScore);
```

Above as ES6

```js
var arr = [{ name: "John", score: "8.8" }, { name: "John", score: "8.6" }, { name: "John", score: "9.0" }, { name: "John", score: "8.3" }, { name: "Tom", score: "7.9" }],
    avgScore = arr.reduce(((sum, count) => (avg, person) => person.name === "John" ? (sum += +person.score) / ++count : avg)(0, 0), 0);

console.log(avgScore);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another ES6 variant, which (ab)uses the third argument of `reduce` as temporary storage, and calls `reduce` again for a chained calculation of the average from the sum and count:

```js
const arr = [
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.8"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.6"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "9.0"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.3"},
  {"name": "Tom",  "score": "7.9"}
];

const avg = arr.reduce( ([sum, count], {name, score}, i) =>
                        (i = name == 'John', [sum + i * score, count + i]), [0, 0] )
               .reduce( (sum, count) => sum/count );

console.log(avg);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution using custom object as ***initialValue*** parameter for `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
var arr = [{"name": "John", "score": "8.8"},{"name": "John", "score": "8.6"}, {"name": "John", "score": "9.0"}, {"name": "John", "score": "8.3"}, {"name": "Tom",  "score": "7.9"}];

var result = arr.reduce(function (r, o) {
    if (o.name === 'John') ++r.count && (r.sum += Number(o.score));
    return r;
}, {sum: 0, count: 0});

console.log(result.sum/result.count);  // `John's` average score
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one line code to get average score

```
let avgScore = arr.reduce((sum, a) => { return sum + parseFloat(a.score) },0)/(arr.length||1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [
    {"name": "John", "score": "8.8"},
      {"name": "John", "score": "8.6"},
      {"name": "John", "score": "9.0"},
      {"name": "John", "score": "8.3"},
      {"name": "Tom",  "score": "7.9"}
    ];

    const johnAvgScore = function(scores) {
      return scores.filter(score => score.name === 'John').reduce((acc, score, i, arr) => acc + parseFloat(score.score)/ arr.length, 0)
      
      }
      
    console.log(johnAvgScore(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IIFE to confine `count` to a private scope:

```js
var arr = [
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.8"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.6"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "9.0"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.3"},
  {"name": "Tom",  "score": "7.9"}
];

var avgScore = arr.reduce(
  (function() {
    var count = 0;

    return function (average, person) {
      if (person.name == "John") {
        count += 1;
        return average * (count - 1) / count + parseFloat(person.score) / count;
      }
      return average;
    };
  })(),
  0
);

console.log(avgScore);
```

Comment: Dear downvoter: Please leave a comment explaining the reason for your downvote. My answer fulfills OP's requirements, but nevertheless if my answer is lacking I'd appreciate the opportunity to improve it.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance.  I did not purposely downvote your solution.  I just accepted the one I thought best met the requirements.  I did not realize I could accept multiple solutions.

Comment: You cannot *accept* multiple solutions. Voting does not have this limitation though. But only downvote if an answer does not meet the expectations. Upvote when you find it useful, even if not accepted.

Comment: @RandellD Did you click the down-arrow? If so, you can retract your downvote by clicking it again. This won't change your accepted answer. (As you've discovered, there are several good ways to solve this problem; I don't mind at all that you accepted a different answer.)

Comment: I did not click the down-arrow.

Comment: @RandellD Then it was someone else. You're off the hook!

Answer (score 0):

A 2-pass works well without extra calculations, globals, or wrapper objects:

```
var arr = [
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.8"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.6"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "9.0"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.3"},
  {"name": "Tom",  "score": "7.9"}
];


var avgScore = arr.filter(x=>x.name=="John")
   .reduce(function(v, n, c, r) {
        return r.length-1 === c ? 
            (v + +n.score) / r.length : 
             v + +n.score;
    },0);

console.log(avgScore);
```

If you are doing several different shapes, you should work in arrays of primitives so you can re-use methods:

```
var arr = [
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.8"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.6"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "9.0"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.3"},
  {"name": "Tom",  "score": "7.9"}
];

// define a few simple helpers
function pluck(o){ return o[this];}    
function avg (v, n, c, r) { // calcs an average w/o a sum
        return r.length-1 === c ? 
            (v + n) / r.length : 
            v + n ;
}

//now use the helpers to write succinct custom code:
var avgScore = arr.filter(x=>x.name=="John")
   .map(pluck, "score")
   .reduce(avg, 0);

console.log(avgScore);
```

The orig idea came from a custom report generator where users could pass in parameters and do some calcs on the backend without running custom code. the lib of generic methods such as *avg* can be used without a custom callback function. it's different, so i mention it...

Comment: What do you mean by "*without extra calculations*"?

Comment: @Bergi: a running sum/avg in a shell object

Comment: This solution does, however, iterate over the same data twice (well, three times in the second example), which will probably cancel out any performance gain from avoiding "extra calculations."

Comment: @Jordan: for-loops would be much faster, "functional" is about writing concise semantic code.

Comment: I still really dislike that `r.length-1 === c ? …` hack

Comment: @Bergi: yeah, there's no other way to get that, without bind, but bind kills reduce perf...

Comment: A simple helper function wrapped *around* the `reduce` calculation would do… `function avg(arr) { return arr.reduce(sum, 0) / arr.length }` `avg(arr.filter(…).map(…))`

Comment: interesting. i wonder if the extra closure would negate the r.length "penalty". it seems like V8 caches the length anyway, even if it's ugly. something to consider and try, thanks!

Comment: I didn't care so much about the penalty of accessing `r.length`, but about the penalty of evaluating the condition. And of course about the ugliness of the construct :-)

Answer (score 0):

This function takes the filter as an argument if you would want to filter on something else another time. It also uses filteredPersons.length; instead of count.

```
var arr = [
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.8"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.6"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "9.0"},
  {"name": "John", "score": "8.3"},
  {"name": "Tom",  "score": "7.9"}
];

function filterJohn(person){
  return person.name === 'John';
};

function calculateAverageScore(persons, filterFunc){
  const filteredPersons = persons.filter(filterFunc);
  return filteredPersons.reduce((sum, person) => { return sum +   parseFloat(person.score); }, 0)/filteredPersons.length;
};

calculateAverageScore(arr, filterJohn);
```