# Can I drop IIFE when I have const inside function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a function `myFunction` which in it's body uses results of other function `otherFunction` and those results are constant per every invocation.

```
function myFunction() {
  doSomething(otherFunction());
}
```

In the past I used IIFE-s to invoke `otherFunction` only once and so optimize the code:

```
var myFunction = (function() {
  let otherFunctionResult = otherFunction();

  return function() {
    doSomething(otherFunctionResult);
  };
}());
```

I wonder if ES6 `const` keyword would achieve the same result without using IIFE:

```
function myFunction() {
  const OTHER_FUNCTION_RESULT = otherFunction();
  doSomething(OTHER_FUNCTION_RESULT);
}
```

Can I expect `const` to be optimized so that `otherFunction` is invoked only once? That would greatly simplify the code.

Comment: Did you try it?  Did you note whether `otherFunction` was called more than once?

Comment: It doesn't. It will run every time, according to my tests. The IIFE still seems to be the best way to go.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Good advice ; ). I've just ran it both in Node and Firefox and other function gets invoked every time when declared with `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `OTHER_FUNCTION_RESULT` is declared as `const` doesn't mean it's only ever called once:

```js
function callOften(){
  const test = init(); // This is a `const`, but does it get called more often?
}

function init(){
  console.log('Init Called');
  return 1;
}

callOften();
callOften();
callOften();
```

Basically, your IIFE is one way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [you don't need IIFEs any more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33534485/1048572) in ES6. However, you seem to confuse `const` with what `static` does in other languages. You still need to initialise it outside of the function if you want to invoke `otherFunction` only once. It would look like this:

```
var myFunction;
{ // block scope!
  let otherFunctionResult = otherFunction(); // `const` works the same here

  myFunction = function() {
    doSomething(otherFunctionResult);
  };
}
```

Admittedly, an IIFE is still nicer to read if your module has a result (here: the function) that is supposed to be stored in a non-local variable.