# JavaScript experts: Do block-scopes with `{}` and anonymous functions both help garbage-collection?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, v8, anonymous-function, spidermonkey

In the book "You don't know JS: scopes & closures", Kyle simpson states that a block-scoped variable helps with garbage collection, here is the specific example:

```
function process(data) {
// do something interesting
}

{
let someReallyBigData = {};
process(someReallyBigData);
}

var btn = document.getElementById("my_button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function click(evt) {
console.log("Clicked!");    
}, false);
```

Now the above example is supposed to help with garbage-collection since the variable `someReallyBigData` will be dropped from memory as soon as the block ends, unlike this example, which doesn't help with garbage-collection:

```
function process(data) {
// do something interesting
}

var someReallyBigData = {};

process(someReallyBigData);

var btn = document.getElementById("my_button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function click(evt) {
console.log("Clicked!");    
}, false);
```

Now I am sure this guy is correct about the examples he provided (the first one); however, i am wondering whether or not everything would be the same if we used an anonymous IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) along with a normal `var` instead of the `{}` curly braces and the `let` variable. Let me turn that into an example:

```
function process(data) {
// do something interesting
}

(function(){
var someReallyBigData = {};
process(someReallyBigData);
}());

var btn = document.getElementById("my_button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function click(evt) {
console.log("Clicked!");    
}, false);
```

Looking at it from the surface, they both should do the same thing; since just as the block-scoped `someReallyBigData` variable could not be accessed anymore by anything after the block of code had executed, the code inside the anonymous function cannot be accessed by anything once it has executed, by anything, from anywhere.

So, do they really have the same effect on the garbage-collection mechanisms of the Javascript engine ? I was almost certain this was the case until I googled "anonymous function garbage-collection" and almost all the material that showed up said only negative things like "anonymous functions cause memory leaks" and etc.

I would be glad if someone could shed some light on this thing.

Please don't forget that my question is a bit specific to the examples I provided, thanks!

Comment: Probably use a block here. IIFEs shouldnt be much worse, however theres no real usecase for them either.

Comment: @Jonasw The book states that the first example helps some engines (it is said to be engine-dependent) with their garbage-collection, since the engine will be able to drop the `someReallyBigData` variable from memory as soon as the block ends (first example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(V8 developer here.) Yes, there are several ways to make objects unreachable, including at least all of the following:

- Put stuff in `let`-declared variables in a block scope
- Put stuff into an IIFE
- Clear the variable (`var` or `let`) when you're done with it: `someReallyBigData = null;`

The end result will be the same in all cases: objects that are no longer reachable are eligible for garbage collection.

Other notes based on the discussion here:

- The advice quoted in the question makes sense for top-level code. Within a reasonably sized function, I wouldn't worry about it -- the function will probably return soon enough that there is no difference, so you don't need to burden yourself with such considerations.
- There's a big difference between "an object *can* be freed now" and "an object *will* be freed now". Letting something go out of scope does not cause it to be freed immediately, and does not cause the garbage collector to run more often. It just means that whenever the garbage collector next decides to go looking for garbage, the object in question will be eligible.
- IIFEs are IIFEs regardless of whether they're anonymous or not. Example:

  ```
  (function I_have_a_name() {
    var someReallyBigData = ...;
  })();
  // someReallyBigData can be collected now.
  I_have_a_name();  // ReferenceError: I_have_a_name is not defined
  ```
- Creating closures in and of itself does not keep things alive. However, if closures reference variables in their outer scope, then (of course!) those can't be collected as long as the closure is around. Example:

  ```
  var closure = (function() {
    var big_data_1 = ...;
    var big_data_2 = ...;
    return function() { return big_data_1.foo; }
  })();
  // big_data_2 can be collected at this point.
  closure();  // This needs big_data_1.
  // big_data_1 still cannot be collected, closure might need it again.
  closure = null;
  // big_data_1 can be collected now.
  ```
- The optimizing compiler has little influence on all this. It usually operates on a per-function bases, and usually the top-level is not optimized (because most logic tends to be in functions). *Within* a function, the optimizing compiler is very well aware of the lifetimes of objects (that's part of what it means to be an optimizing compiler).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript only has block level scope when you use the **[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)** or `const` keywords in declarations. Just because you have `{}` alone does not create block-level scope (as is the case in most other languages).

Aside from that, garbage collection is implementation dependent and you would most likely not notice any difference in performance due to block scoping.

Anonymous functions can have an impact on garbage collection because the function can be set up in such a way that it doesn't have to be stored for potential calling later. A good example of this would be a function that needs to run only once (i.e. when the document is fully parsed):

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ . . . });
```

However, that doesn't mean that all anonymous functions provide this benefit because the function could wind up being stored (i.e. if it is returned from a function and then captured in a variable) or **if the anonymous function sets up closures, then all bets are off.**

Also, be aware that you can't unit test anonymous functions as simply as you can named functions.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just didn't know how to turn "a block-level scope with let" into a noun for the title of the question so the title is a bit misleading. What i mean is a  `let` variable inside of a `{}` block.

Comment: Also forgot to mention that You Don't Know JS also stated that the whole helps-with-garbage-collection thing was not engine-neutral, My bad. But still, what is it like with the popular engines like V8 and SpiderMonkey ?

Comment: @Taurus It's tough to say because implementation details are not always public. Keep in mind that dumping memory as soon as it is possible to do so is not always better in terms of performance. The garbage collector would have to run more often in those cases and that doesn't come without a cost.

Comment: @scott marcus afaik V8 uses *stop the world* if it needs to free memory ( so it actually just garbagge collects if the space is needed).

Comment: @Jonasw But "needing" to free memory is not the same a "being able" to free up some memory.

Comment: A common use for DOMContentLoaded or an IIFE at the end of the body is to place the whole logic into a single function (out of the reach of the global scope). There's hardly any garbage collection after these functions are executed, almost everything must be kept in the memory because of massive closuring.

Comment: @Teemu but theoretically, after all those closures are successfully executed, everything will be garbage-collected ? Would the same thing happen if everything was in the global scope and everything there successfully executed ?

Comment: @Taurus Successfully executing isn't the same thing as lexical scope.

Comment: @ScottMarcus could you elaborate on that ?

Comment: @Taurus JavaScript is "lexically scoped", meaning that *where* you declare your statements determines their scope, not when they are executed. So, just because something has executed doesn't mean it's out of scope. It all depends on the declaration. The two concepts are related, but not the same thing.

Comment: @Taurus 1) Very theoretically, yes. In practice, never. Scott already seems to have answered the second question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i get that Javascript uses Lexical Scope and not dynamic (which very few use most languages nowadays, according to Wikipedia). But in the example that Teemu provided "if we put everything inside of an IIFE" (anonymous IIFE i assume), then after that function and everything inside of it finishes executing, won't it be garbage-collected (since there is no way to execute that function again, and all its contents are inaccessible outside) ?

Comment: @Taurus Yes, assuming that the code in that IIFE didn't set up any closures or make any connections to longer lived elements.

Comment: @ScottMarcus so one little long-polling request to the server-side would prevent everything declared previously (or everything that memory has stored from the previous code) from being cleaned up ? If the answer is yes, sorry for asking, just had to be sure.

Comment: @Taurus Yes, that's a good example that would keep the function alive and well. As for closure situations, the variables that **do not** have closures around them can be collected. Just not the ones still used in closures.

Comment: @ScottMarcus regarding your comment "Keep in mind that dumping memory as soon as it is possible to do so is not always better in terms of performance. The garbage collector would have to run more often in those cases and that doesn't come without a cost.", shouldn't that be the engine's concern ? So Javascript tells us to clean up the memory whenever we can, while engines tell us "no, don't clean it up too much".

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering whether or not everything would be the same if we used an anonymous IIFE

Sure that's possible, it's what transpilers do to emulate block scopes as well. However IIFEs look a bit awkward, block scopes with `let`/`const` variables are *easier to use*. See also [Will const and let make the IIFE pattern unnecessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33534485/1048572).

> Now the first example is supposed to help with garbage-collection since the variable `someReallyBigData` will be dropped from memory as soon as the block ends, unlike the second example, which doesn't help with garbage-collection.

Notice that the word is *helps*, not *enables*. Today's engines [can garbage-collect the variable just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5326300/1048572), as their optimiser sees that it's not used in the preserved closure. The block scope only makes this kind of static analysis *easier*.

Comment: "as their optimiser sees that it's not used in the preserved closure" when can the optimiser see that, surely not during compilation, right ? If during compilation, that raises tens of questions regarding scope generally.

Comment: @Taurus Sure during compilation, when else? It's static analysis - if the variable doesn't occur in the function, it's not referenced from it. Of course things like `eval` destroy this reasoning.

Comment: That book, You Don't Know JS, has tens of "could be accessed from there for all compiler knows" parts, aren't all those parts sort of nullified if the compiler does see all the accesses in the code pre-execution ?

Comment: @Taurus Not sure what specifically you are referring to. Sometimes the compiler knows something, sometimes it doesn't. It depends on the sophistication of the engine and the analysed structure.