# How to fix 'Function declarations should not be placed in blocks' error in Javascript es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, jshint, iife

After a long time without using Javascript, I try to do understand what is es6, modules and iife.

So I make a little piece of code :

```
{
    'use strict';

    let version = '1.0.0';

    function init(){
        /* ... */
    }

    window.Test = {
        version: version,
        init: init
    };
}
```

And jshint returns this error : Function declarations should not be placed in blocks. Use a function expression or move the statement to the top of the outer function.

But, if I use the es5 format (function(){...}()) there is no problem. So what did I misunderstand ?

Furthermore, if someone have some time to answer some questions more :

- 'use strict' is necessary or redundant ?
- I use an iife, but is it a module too ? (I think, I have very misunderstand this part)
- window.Test is it the best way to export my variable Test ?

Thank you in advance for your answers, Sam.

EDIT : a good video to understand module : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJWALEoGge4

Comment: _"I use an iife"_ - No, there's no IIFE in your example.

Comment: What do you do with this code? Is it imported by something else, or does init() do everything you want to do?

Comment: Why is it not an IIFE ? I thought that was the case after seeing these sites : 
http://es6-features.org/#BlockScopedFunctions 
https://jack.ofspades.com/es6-iife-with-fat-arrow-functions/

Comment: I use it in a html page and the function init was just for the example, I have a LOT of functions to put in this script and I want to use it it like an API by using the Test variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And jshint returns this error: Function declarations should not be placed in blocks. Use a function expression or move the statement to the top of the outer function.

That means that jshint doesn't understand ES6. Or you might need to configure it so that it does.

> `'use strict'` is necessary or redundant?

The one you used here doesn't work, as directive prologues can only be placed in functions (or on the begin of a module or script), but not in a block.

> I use an iife, but is it a module too?

No, you are not using an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-iife-construct-in-javascript) here. It's just a block, but [that's ok](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33534485/1048572).

It does implement the module pattern ("create an object with access to privately-scoped internals"), but it is not an ES6 module.

> `window.Test` is it the best way to export my variable `Test`?

No, I would recommend declaring it with `var`.

Comment: I think, I understand now. Thanks.