# How are IIFEs useful post ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures, iife

I'm learning JavaScript and I understand the general function types, closures, etc. But with IIFEs my initial reaction was "if its immediately invoked, why not just inline it". So I went and read [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/4-practical-use-cases-for-iifes-in-javascript-6481dcb0ba7d) that describes "4 Practical Use Cases" for IIFEs. However, two of which are related to circumventing the scoping issues that come with `var`s (which are no longer a concern post ES6 with `let` and `const` being introduced). A third one deals with global variable naming conflicts (what namespaces generally deal with in C++). And, from what I can tell, Import Aliasing (which was also introduced in ES6) solves this problem.

The remaining use case is regarding closures:

The author claims that combining a closure with an IIFE provides us with "two great benefits": 1) the scopes of variables is secured, and 2) you can modify variables inside a function from the outside. However, from my understanding of closures, you can have both those benefits with just a regular closure.

For instance,

```js
const IIFEclosure = (() => {
  let v = 10;
  return {
    value: _ => v,
    set: newValue => v = newValue,
  };
})();

const handle = () => {
  let v = 10;
  return {
    value: _ => v,
    set: newValue => v = newValue,
  };
};
const closure1 = handle();
const closure2 = handle();

console.log(IIFEclosure.value(), closure1.value(), closure2.value()) // 10 10 10
IIFEclosure.set(20);
closure1.set(30);
closure2.set(40);
console.log(IIFEclosure.value(), closure1.value(), closure2.value()) // 20 30 40
```

The only difference I can see here is that you can create multiple instances of the regular closure using `handle` while with `IIFEclosure` there can be only one since its immediately invoked in place and has no "handle". I guess it has the upside of not polluting the namespace with an extra variable name. I am not sure if in practice having a closure that can only be instantiated once is useful or not. But, other than that, as far as I can tell, both benefits mentioned above are satisfied in both examples.

So if my above reasoning is valid, this leads me to opening question; what, if any, are the benefits/usecases of IIFEs in post ES6 JavaScript?

Comment: See [Will const and let make the IIFE pattern unnecessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33534485/1048572) and related questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For closures there is still a small advantage: the function itself can be **anonymous**, avoiding one (function) variable. For instance, in your example, the non-IIFE has the `handle` as extra variable. If you want to minimise the littering of the current scope (maybe even the global scope) then IIFEs are still useful.

I also find IIFE useful at the top level for using `await` -- although that would be named an IIAFE:

```
(async () => {
    const response = await fetch("....");
    const object = await response.json();
    // ...
    const result = await lookup(object.id);
    // ...
})();
```

Since ECMAScript 2022 introduced [top-level await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await), it is no longer needed to have such `async` wrappers in *modules*.

As to the use case of global name aliasing, that one can also be solved with a plain block:

```
{
    const $ = jQuery;
    // Here comes $-referencing code that will not conflict with "outside" $ use.
}
```

Comment: seems to me like the main benefit of IIFEs at this point is keeping clean namespaces/scopes. Regarding your `await` example, do you mind expanding on that? how are IIFEs useful in that context?

Comment: Awaits cannot be used outside a function in the main script, only in modules. So if you don't use modules you need an async function.

Answer (score 1):

Whether to use an IIFE or not is like a more general question whether to store an intermediate computation in a variable. It depends on the context and your sense of style. Since function expressions are usually complex and reusable, in most cases you want to store them, however, there are cases when a bare expression works better.

Example:

```
let intersection = (a, b) => {
    let sa = new Set(a)
    return b.filter(x => sa.has(x))
}
```

Of course, this is overly verbose and we'd really like it to be an oneliner. Let's use an IIFE then!

```
let intersection = (a, b) => (sa => b.filter(x => sa.has(x)))(new Set(a))
```

(Though I'd personally factor that into two functions).

Comment: Much simpler: `b.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(a))` :-)

Comment: I'd rather write `b.filter((sa => x => sa.has(x))(new Set(a)))` to keep the scope minimal