# In ES6 what is new spec, "block-level function declaration" mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm going down the es6 compatibility table trying to learn [Here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#block-level-function-note).

in the **bindings** section it says "block-level function declaration?".  I'm unable to find any blogs or documentation besides the offical [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) on that combinations of words.

**Question:**  What is "block-level function declaration" referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the example kangax is testing for:

```
alert(function(){
    'use strict';
    function f() { return 1; }
    {
      function f() { return 2; }
    }
    return f() === 1;
}());
```

it means that function "hoisting" behaves the same way as `let` (vs `var`).

In ES5, braces were "decoration", unless they appeared after a few keywords like `for`, `if`, `try`, etc. so, the 2nd `f()` would "clobber" the 1st, but in ES6-compat runtimes, the 2nd `f()` is private to the block and thus doesn't replace the name `f` defined by the 1st function.

In ES6 braces (`{ ... }`) mean a block, even without a preceding keyword. That said, i don't see many arbitrary blocks in ES6 code, maybe just from lack of practice, ignorance, or perhaps just from lack of need; function scope works pretty well in JS.

Comment: Re your last remark: I guess you're just not noticing the myriads of `for (let…) { … }` blocks any more, but they are definitely there :-) Admittedly function *declarations* inside them are sparse.

Comment: @Bergi: my last remark continues my 2nd to last, so _arbitrary_ means non-ES5 blocks, for _scope_ only...

Answer (score 1):

Checkout SO [What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6) question.

You find a nice description of question and really verbose answer.

Comment: Can't argue with that :-)

Comment: @Bergi ohh, sure, it's hard to argue with own  answer ))