# Block Scoped Function ECMAScript 6 Strange Behaviour

Tags: javascript, function, scope, ecmascript-6, block

I was reading the new features in ECMA6. One of the new features is [**Block Scoped Functions**](http://es6-features.org/#BlockScopedFunctions) . That means we can have a same name for functions in different blocks. As in the code below `block1 foo()` logs `1` then similarly `block2 foo()` logs 2 and `block0 foo() or global scope` logs 4. And that is the expected result. But what i can't understand is that Why does the last `console.log(foo())` logs 1 and not 4 because it is under `block0 or global scope` instead it logs 1 which is `block1 foo()`.

```js
//block0
function foo () { return 4 }
console.log(foo());//will log 4
{
  //block1
    function foo () { return 1 }
    console.log(foo());//will log 1
    {
    //block2
        function foo () { return 2 }//a block level function
        console.log(foo());//will log 2
    }
    console.log(foo());//will again log 1
}
console.log(foo());//should log 4 but logs 1 why?
```

Now again if I enclose the above code into a another block it works as expected. This is a bit confusing to me. What actually is causing this behviour?

```js
{//block0
function foo () { return 4 }
console.log(foo());//will log 4
{
  //block1
    function foo () { return 1 }
    console.log(foo());//will log 1
    {
    //block2
        function foo () { return 2 }
        console.log(foo());//will log 2
    }
    console.log(foo());//will again log 1
}
console.log(foo());//will log 4 but 
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31419897/1048572) already?

Comment: Is there any difference between block0 being a function or global scope? Also, in what browser, in what environment (console?) are you testing this?

Comment: @Bergi i have tested it in chrome and IE11. And block0 over here iis global scope.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure *strict mode* is enabled. Since it is enabled in modules by default, I guess your sample code doesn't show that. [Kangax's compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-block-level_function_declaration) shows an appropriate test.

```js
"use strict";
//block0
function foo () { return 4 }
console.log(foo());//will log 4
{
  //block1
    function foo () { return 1 }
    console.log(foo());//will log 1
    {
    //block2
        function foo () { return 2 }//a block level function
        console.log(foo());//will log 2
    }
    console.log(foo());//will again log 1
}
console.log(foo());//logs 4
```

Comment: that means if i don't use `strict` mode `block scoped functions` will not work properly?

Answer (score 1):

*Fully amended answer for in-depth explanation*

First things first: the problem appears because you are not using `use strict` mode. What is the difference in `strict` and `non-strict` mode in this case? The difference is the way simple block scoping is treated.

In both modes a brackets block creates a scope. Declarations inside that scope can be viewed inside the scope itself and inside further enclosed scopes.

```
{ // level 1 scope
  function asdf() {alert("asdf");}
  { // level 2 scope
    asdf(); // Yay I can use it!
  }
}
```

**However**, in ES5 and in ES6 `non strict`, a simple block scope is *not* treated as a true enclosing scope. Declarations inside a simple block scope get hoisted all the way up to the first true enclosing scope they can find. In those cases, a true enclosing scope is either a function's scope or the global scope.

The above example, in `non strict` mode is equivalent to this:

```
var asdf0 = undefined; // Haha! The declaration has been hoisted up to the global scope!
{ // level 1 scope
  function asdf1() {alert("asdf");}
  asdf0 = asdf1; // The definition is ready and will be assigned to its declaration
  { // level 2 scope
    asdf1(); // Yay I can use it!
  }
}
asdf0(); // Damn! I have access outside of the block scope due to hoisting! Should have used strict mode...
```

If we enclose the previous logic into a `function` however, we don't get hoisting to the global scope, only up to the function's scope.

```
function scopeBlocker() {
  var asdf0 = undefined;
  ...
  ...
}
asdf0(); // Exception! Wasn't hoisted all the way up to the global scope!
```

Now, to come to your example, because you were **not** using `strict mode` you fell into the trap of old block scoping. In your first attempt, the *second* declaration inside the *first* block scope was hoisted all the way up to its enclosing scope and replaced the first `foo` declaration. Now because *hoisting happens only once*, the following declarations were **not** hoisted thus not replacing anything. In the second case, adding the top level block scope forced the first `foo` declaration to be hoisted to the global enclosing scope and thus the second `foo` declaration was now **not hoisted** because the `foo` name had already been hoisted.

It is indeed a weird behavior, but I believe that's what's happening here.

Comment: ya thats what i not able to figure out. Why in the first case it logs 1 and second case 4. Becuase `foo()` logging 4 is defined first and should be captured in window and not the one logging 1.

Comment: @Manish have amended my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on where you are running your code. Maybe this feature isn't supported just yet. Your code snippet logs 4, 1, 2, 2, 2 (Firefox browser).

Logically your code should log as you say.

Where exactly do you test the code?

Comment: I tested in Chrome and IE11. Issue is the last `console.log()` in both snippets that logs a different value then expected for the first snippet. But second snippet logs the correct expected values