# Error sometimes thrown with JavaScript code block

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I'm using code blocks to simulate static function variables a la C. Here's the basic setup:

```js
{
    let bob = 5;
    function b() {
        console.log(bob++);
    }
}
```

Now in chrome this compiles just fine with no complaints. In Safari however, I get a

> `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'bob'. Expected a ':' following the property name 'let'.`

I have no idea what's causing this discrepancy as both Chrome and Safari handle ECMAScript 6.

Comment: It would help if you'd post the *actual* code, and not a summary.

Comment: as you have enclosed it into an object, all of those are now properties, so try:

`{ bob: 5, b: () => { console.log(bob++) }`

Comment: @DominikMatis - No, freestanding blocks don't create objects. If the code above is as presented, it creates a freestanding block with code inside.

Comment: @Pointy this is the actual (reduced) code that is failing. Try for yourself.

Comment: So that's **all** of the context? Is it in a script loaded with a `<script>` tag, and there's no other code? Is it in a function or at the outer scope? The thing is, that's a simple piece of code and it would be very surprising for Safari to do something differently than Chrome if that is **all** the code involved.

Comment: @Pointy literally copy and paste that in a developer console and it will fail with that error.

Comment: No it won't because I'm running Firefox on Linux.

Comment: Yep, Safari's bug

Comment: Putting a `function` declaration in a block like that is questionable, at best

Comment: @Pointy - In loose mode, absolutely. it's well defined in strict mode (though even then it's a bit...odd...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the code is in loose mode and you're declaring a function in a block. Function declarations in blocks were only standardized in ES2015 and, well, they make sense in strict mode but in loose mode they're...weird.

In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), your code works, possibly as you expect or possibly not. `bob` is accessible to `b`...and neither `bob` nor `b` accessible outside that block, unless you do something to expose them outside it.

Here's an example you can use to test it on both Safari and iOS Safari (I have only the latter available to me). This version gives an error:

```
<script>
window.onerror = e => {
    document.body.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", String(e));
};
</script>
<script>
{
    let bob = 5;
    function b() {
        document.body.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", bob++);
    }

    b();
}
</script>
```

The error is:

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: bob`

This version works:

```
<script>
window.onerror = e => {
    document.body.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", String(e));
};
</script>
<script>
"use strict"; // <============================
{
    let bob = 5;
    function b() {
        document.body.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", bob++);
    }

    b();
}
</script>
```

I have also replicated the behavior in the latest version of JavaScriptCore (Apple's JavaScript engine), v265499. I installed¹ and ran it locally (changing `console.log`/`insertAdjacentText` to `print`, which is available in most of the raw engine executables) and get the same error in loose mode and not in strict mode.

---

If you want `b` available outside the block, you're probably better off doing something like this:

```
"use strict";
const b = (() => {
    let bob = 5;
    return function b() {
        console.log(bob++);
    };
})();
b();
```

Which is a **lot** bulkier, but... Alternatively, with `let`:

```
"use strict";
let b;
{
    let bob = 5;
    b = function b() {
        print(bob++);
    };
}
b();
```

---

¹ Using the very handy [`jsvu` utility](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsvu).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247362/safari-bug-with-block-scoped-variables - oh wait maybe not

Comment: @Pointy - Ack! Function declarations in blocks! I'm such an idiot.

Comment: Well yes, but the error that the OP reports is weird, if `function` placement is the problem, seems to me.

Comment: @Pointy - Oh agreed. But the semantics of function declarations in blocks in loose mode are weird (to the extent they're defined; this may not match any of the limited number of common behaviors that could be standardized for loose mode). doubly so when you throw Annex B stuff at it. :-D I just feel like an idiot. It's not like there isnt' an entire section on them in my book!

Comment: Oh great. Now I have to google what strict/loose mode is :D

Comment: @theEpsilon - LOL Sorry -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode. Basically, strict mode is a mode added to JavaScript in ES5 to bring some really, really problematic behaviors under control, and to make it possible to specify slightly different, more rational behaviors for code that opts into the new strict variant. You do that by adding `"use strict";` at the top of the compilation unit (loosely, "file") or the top of a function. Also note that JavaScript modules and `class` constructs are strict by default. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, Safari is interpreting your block as an object literal. The syntax is valid, but Safari seems to be choking on it.

When I tried this out in my own console, I was able to get it working by placing a statement immediately following the block:

```js
{ let bob = 5; function b(){ console.log(bob++); } } console.log('foo');
```

However, this seems to hoist the function out of the block scope without creating a closure, causing a `ReferenceError` claiming that it can't find variable `bob`.

I tried explicitly wrapping it in a function and starting that function with the `use strict` declaration, in case it was not running in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#Block_scoping_rules_with_let_const_or_function_declaration_in_strict_mode) as that can change the behavior:

```js
function strict() {
  'use strict';
  {
    let bob = 5;
    function b() {
      console.log(bob++);
    }
    return b;
  } 
}
strict()();
```

And it worked!

TL:DR; block handling is weird in loose mode. Use strict mode when defining functions inside blocks.

Comment: The function *should* be hoisted out of the block scope, because function declarations are scoped the old-fashioned way.

Comment: My wording was bad. I've edited the answer to clarify that it should create a closure, but isn't.