# How JS hoisting works with block statement?

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

In this following snipet, I just want to understand why `console.log(abc in this);` is print true , but in next line `console.log(abc);` getting `undefined`

```
console.log(this.abc);//undefined
console.log(abc in this);//true
console.log(abc);//undefined
{
    function abc(){
        console.log("hello");
    }
}
console.log(abc); //ƒ abc(){console.log("hello");
```

Could anyone of you explain how Hoisting and Block statement working in this case?

Comment: What is `this`? Where do you run this code?

Comment: here this refer "window" object

Comment: @JonasW. Sloppy mode, global scope?

Comment: @JonasW. Oh. It was edited.

Comment: @Rokas you completely altered the question! I've rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sloppy mode, `this` refers to the global object. A function inside a plain *non-function* block like that will have its variable name hoisted to the *outer* scope, but the actual function will not be assigned to the outer variable (to the window property) until the inner block is executed.

See here for details:

[What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6)

As explained in that other question, to the interpreter, your code looks something like this:

```js
window.abc = undefined; // top-level hoisting assigns to window properties
console.log(window.abc); // undefined
console.log(window.abc in window); // true
console.log(window.abc); // undefined
{
  var _abc = function abc() {
    console.log("hello");
  };
  window.abc = _abc;
}
console.log(window.abc); //ƒ abc(){console.log("hello");
```

The reason `abc in this` is true is because `abc` *has* been initialized as a property of the window object, but it hasn't been assigned a value yet. It's similar to what's happening here:

```js
const obj = { foo: undefined };
console.log('foo' in obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, with `console.log(abc in this);` it check if it is there, which it is, hence logging `true`, though you can't access it yet, hence getting `undefined` for the other two `console.log` executing before the function declaration.

Comment: But why is it there (and where exactly)? It's declared inside a block scope!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know why that happen the answer is simple, hoisting moves all the declarations to the top of his scope, so:

```
console.log(this.abc); //undefined
console.log(abc in this); //true
console.log(abc); //undefined

function abc() {
  console.log("hello");
}

console.log(abc); //ƒ abc(){console.log("hello");
```

so in the inner function, the function abc() is declared at the top of the current scope staying almost at the same position, but just the declaration, so the var abc is declared then assigned, when you try access at the bottom he already knows the function, in the first console.log where you get undefined

console.log(abc) the function _abc is not decalred yet, but in the second example you have access to it because it access the windows object and get the abc.

so in short terms, javascript first initialize variables, since at the second console.log all the variables are already declared and they are declared at the window object, accessing abc on this works fine.

Comment: Your snippet looks like it was copied from @CertainPerformance's answer

Comment: yeah, wanted to copy the question, my fault sorry