# limit the scope of contents in js file

Tags: javascript

I recently encountered a situation where i have A.js, B.js and C.js .  All those JS files importing a same module. ( ex: `const hello = require ("hello");`) . 
While running them together i get following SyntaxError in the console

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'home' has already been declared`

I'm loading those JS files from HTML using Script tag like below

```
<script src="../js/A.js"></script>
<script src="../js/B.js"></script>
<script src="../js/C.js"></script>
```

Moving content of each js file into `{ }` curly braces is one option to fix the SyntaxError.

But i want to know whether this({}) is right solution or do we have any other better solutions to address this situation

Comment: Create a IIFE in each file to create its own scope.

Comment: How are you using `require ("hello");` in the browser? What module format/loader are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution would be to use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Basically, wrap your code in a function and call it at the same time. This both protects the code's scope and prevents people viewing the page from accessing your data in their developer tools.

```
(function() {
    /* your code here */
})();
```

A more modern, and arguable more correct, solution would be to use [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). Then you can use [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) instead of `require`, and you can organize your code a bit more like you would expect from Python or Java.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<script type="module" src=".../module.js"></script>
<script type="module" src=".../src1.js"></script>
<script type="module" src=".../src2.js"></script>
```

```js
// module.js
export const MESSAGE = "Hello, world!";
```

```js
// src1.js (src2.js looks basically the same)
import { MESSAGE } from ".../module.js";
console.log("src1 says:", MESSAGE);
```

However, a few browsers do not support modules. To get around that, you could use a bundler (such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/), or [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/)) to compile your project. These also provide other features (such as code minification). But for a small project, using a bundler may not be worth the effort (though learning to use them will be helpful if you go into web development).

Answer (score 1):

> Moving content of each js file into { } curly braces is one option to fix the SyntaxError.

Yes. That syntax error is only caused by redeclaring a variable that was declared with `let` or `const`, and these are block scoped, so introducing a new block fixes that.

Note that `var`s and `function`s will leak through it though (but redeclaring them won't cause an error¹):

```
 {
    function test() { }
 }

 test();
```

¹ as you usually want strong encapsulation as redeclaring global variables usually causes unpredictable side effects, I'd go with an IIFE, or use ES modules.

Comment: Use strict mode to prevent function declarations from [leaking through block scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31419897/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good habit to have your code wrapped inside an anonymous function as follows

```html
(function(){
    /* all your variables, and functions ... everything goes in here */
})();
```