# Is there a risk that setTimeout will fire twice after I "reset" it?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, race-condition

Sometimes I use the following concept:

```
class ResetableTimeout extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    this.id = -1;
  }
  start(delay) {
    clearTimeout(this.id);
    this.id = setTimeout(() =>{this.emit("done");}, delay);
  }
}
```

Architecture like this may be used for throttling operations for example.

Now I noticed that this may fire twice under these circumstances:

1. `setTimeout` starts timeout
2. `start(delay)` is called and is executing
3. Timeout fires and the callback is pushed in the eventloop, waiting for `start(delay)` to end
4. `clearTimeout` is called, but the timeout is done already
5. `start(delay)` ends and timeout's callback executes
6. `delay` ms later, timeout's callback executes again

Is this possible? If it is possible how to prevent it? If it isn't possible, what prevents it from happening?

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. Essentially, your step 4 is incorrect: calling `clearTimeout()` will prevent the timer callback from being called; it is not "done already".

Comment: @Pointy can you help answering [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151953/how-js-declares-variable-and-function-without-lexical-in-a-statement-block) too whenever you find time mate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `clearTimeout` will remove the timeout from the event queue if the internal timeout already had been fired. It assures that the callback will not run after you called `clearTimeout`.

[In the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps), there is a *list of active timers*, from which the callback to execute is fetched by the timed event loop task, and `clearTimeout` clears the timer in that list so even when the task had already been scheduled it will still check whether the timer is still active before executing the callback.

Comment: Plus 1 for quoting the spec