# Function declaration in block moving temporary value outside of block?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a;
if (true) {
  a = 5;

  function a() {}
  a = 0;
  console.log(a)
}
console.log(a)
```

I saw the code above, a function is declared in {}. I think it would print 0 0, but it prints 0 5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6)

Comment: In strict mode, it logs `0 undefined`.

Comment: @certainPerformance well, that's explainable, but I fail to explain that `a = 5` leaves the block. According to bergi in the dupe, `function a` will be hoisted.

Comment: Seems as if the locally scoped block variable gets copied to the outer block when reaching the function declaration.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following happens:

(1) There exist two variable declarations `a`, one inside the block and one outside of it.

(2) The function declaration gets hoisted, and bound to the inner blocks variable.

(3) `a = 5` is reached, which overrides the block variable.

(4) the function declaration is reached, and the block variable is copied to the outer variable. Both are 5 now.

(5) `a = 0` is reached, which overrides the block variable. The outer variable is not affected by this.

```
 var a¹;
 if (true) {
   function a²() {} // hoisted
   a² = 5;
   a¹ = a²; // at the location of the declaration, the variable leaves the block      
   a² = 0;
  console.log(a²)
}
console.log(a¹);
```

This is actually not really part of the specification, it is part of the [web legacy compatibility semantics](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics), so *don't rely on this code to behave in this way* and always [`"use strict";` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

This is also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6).

Comment: But why once the function declaration is reached, the block variable will be copied to the outer variable?Concluded that from debugger?

Comment: @Chor no, the spec says so. I have no idea why.

Comment: @Chor Because this is the way old browsers behaved with "conditional declaration statements", see e.g. https://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-statements