# function declarations cannot be inside an if statement according to ecmascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecma262

how is it even possible to declare a function inside an *[IfStatement](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-IfStatement)* ? because according to the ecmascript spec only a *[Statement](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-Statement)* can be there.

> if ( Expression ) Statement
>
> if ( Expression ) Statement else Statement

and *[FunctionDeclaration](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-FunctionDeclaration)* isn't a *Statement* but it's a *[Declaration](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-Declaration)*

so maybe i've missed something or maybe Browsers cannot implement such thing nowadays because it may ruin websites that use function declarations inside an if statement.

Comment: The way specs are written in general is confusing. It is understandable where your confusion comes from. Please take a look at the [list of **Statements**](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/grammar-summary.html#sec-statements) in the spec's Grammar Summary. There you will find all things considered to be _statements_ categorized so they are easier to think about. Under the Statement category called Hoistable Declarations - you will,  in-fact, find that a FunctionDeclaration is in the list of things that are statement. Hope this helps.

Comment: @RandyCasburn A *FunctionDeclaration* may be listed in the statements section of the spec, but that doesn't mean there is a production that makes it a *Statement*.

Comment: @Bergi - you could say exactly the same thing about an expression (_doesn't mean there is a production that makes an Expression a Statement_)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Well there's the [*ExpressionStatement* production](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ExpressionStatement) which does just that (sans the semicolon). There is no such production for function declarations. A *FunctionDeclaration* is a not a *Statement*.

Comment: @RandyCasburn but Expression is a Statement because a Statement Can be an ExpressionStatement and ExpressionStatement can be an Expression.

Comment: @Bergi - gotcha.

Comment: @Bergi - you should get all that ambiguity removed! :-)

Answer (score 4):

It *is* not possible to put a function declaration in an `if` statement. Try

```
if (true) function example() {}
```

in strict mode - you'll get a `SyntaxError`. To declare a function inside a conditional branch, you must put it inside a [*Block*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-block), which is a *Statement* (through *BlockStatement*) and can contain *Declaration*s (in a *StatementList*).

> Maybe Browsers cannot implement such thing nowadays because it may ruin websites that use function declarations inside an if statement.

Yes indeed. For web legacy compatibility, [function declarations in `if` statements are allowed in sloppy mode](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarations-in-ifstatement-statement-clauses). Don't write code like that, but browser are allowed to treat it as valid.

Comment: [Don't write code like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58619924/function-declaration-in-block-moving-temporary-value-outside-of-block/58620404#58620404) ...

Answer (score -2):

From the spec:

At the top level of a function or script, inner function declarations are treated like var declarations.

The chain goes like this.

Statement => BlockStatement => StatementList => StatementListItem => Declaration => VarDeclaration

It's all right here, statement list item

https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-StatementListItem

Prior to ECMAScript 2015, the ECMAScript specification did not define the occurrence of a FunctionDeclaration as an element of a Block statement's StatementList. However, support for that form of FunctionDeclaration was an allowable extension and most browser-hosted ECMAScript implementations permitted them.

Comment: statements can contain var declarations

Comment: yes that's right VariableStatement. but what about functions ?

Comment: statements contain statementlist and statementlist contains var declarations

Comment: dude but i haven't spoked about the Block statement. IfStatement doesn't have to contain the BlockStatement it can contain other type of statements and function declarations aren't one of them that's where my whole confusion comes.

Comment: look at the link...

Comment: it's says that Statementlist can be a StatementListItem and StatementListItem can be a Statement or Declaration. Statement if they could be a Statementlist that's mean that you could write a whole Javascript code inside an ifStatement without even using curly braces

Comment: it says an if block can be a statement, and statement can have a statement list, and a statement list can have a var declaration, and a function is treated as a var declaration.

Comment: the curly braces declare the statement list.  thats why you need them if having more than one statement list item, and why you can omit them if only 1 item

Comment: @StevenSpungin "*statement can have a statement list*" - no. Where do you see such a production?

Comment: statement can be a block statement, that can have a statement list. read my post fully @bergi. last paragraph.  'Prior to ECMAScript 2015, the ECMAScript specification did not define the occurrence of a FunctionDeclaration as an element of a Block statement's StatementList'

Comment: Ah, yes, but that is a *contains* relation, not an *is-a* relation.