# javascipt function and var difference when compile

Tags: javascript, function, var

```
var a; 

if (true) {
 a = {a: 2};
 function a() {}
 a.ot = '9'; 
 a = {a: 4};
 console.log('1', a);
}

console.log('2', a);
```

which output is

```
1 {a: 4}
2 {a: 2, ot: "9"}
```

can anyone tell me why? thanks so much

Comment: compile? anway, what output were you expecting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6)

Comment: long story short: this is one of the 634534 black magic pitfalls, that happen, when you don't "use strict";

Answer (score 1):

As @ASDFGerte points out, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461615/2750819) explains the answer but let me just do some bridge work from your example to the example given in the answer.

First of all, lets remove the `if (true)`: it is only relevant that there is a block. Second, let us replace `{a: ...}` with plain strings. The line `a.ot = '9'` is also irrelevant so let us remove that. So now we are down to the following:

```
var a; 

{
 a = 'before func declaration';
 function a() {} 
 a = 'after func declaration';
 console.log('Inside block:', a);
}

console.log('Outside block:', a);
```

The output is as follows:

```
Inside block: after func declaration
Outside block: before func declaration
```

At this point it should be clearer as to how [the example code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461615/2750819) applies. In essence, it is as if the code were written as follows:

```
var a;

{
 let b = function a() {}
 a = 'before func declaration';
 b;
 b = 'after func declaration';
 console.log('Inside block:', b);
}

console.log('Outside block:', a);
```

Comment: Rather `b = 'before func declaration'; a = b;`