# Typescript error : Function declarations are not permitted in blocks in strict mode

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to run a script but I have this error : `Function declarations are not permitted in blocks in strict mode during targeting of the 'ES3' or 'ES5' version. The modules are automatically in strict mode.`

I'm in typescript, here is the script :

```
export default () => {

  if(document.getElementById("myRange")){
    //slider 
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange") as HTMLInputElement;
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    var gainTimeOutput = document.getElementById("time");
    var sliderEco = document.getElementById("myRange-eco") as HTMLInputElement;
    var outputEco = document.getElementById('demo-eco');
    var eco = document.getElementById('eco');
    outputEco.innerHTML = sliderEco.value;
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    function movingSlider(){ <-- Error happens here 
      output.innerHTML = slider.value;
      var convertSlider = parseInt(slider.value); 
      var convertSliderEco = parseInt(sliderEco.value);

      var gainTime = Math.round(convertSlider).toString();
      var gainMoney = (Math.round(convertSlider* 2).toString();

      gainTimeOutput.innerHTML = gainTime + "h"; 
      outputEco.innerHTML = sliderEco.value;
      eco.innerHTML = gainMoney + "€";
    }

    slider.oninput = e => {
      movingSlider()
    };
```

I don't get why, the things is that when I delete my `if(document.getElementById("myRange"))`, it works good, 
Anyone know why I have this error and how should I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much just what the error says. You have a function declaration in a block, whose behavior is [weird](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31419897) across environments and unpredictable before being specified in ES6, so it's not permitted by your setup. Assign a function expression to a variable name instead. Change

```
function movingSlider(){
```

to

```
const movingSlider = function movingSlider(){
```

If you've posted the *full* code of the function being exported, then the code would probably be cleaner *and* the above wouldn't be necessary if you simply returned early if `myRange` doesn't exist:

```
export default () => {
  const slider = document.getElementById<HTMLInputElement>("myRange");
  if (!slider) {
    return;
  }
  // rest of your code
```

This lets you avoid an unnecessary space of indentation throughout the rest of your function.