# `function` declarations are function scoped, but `async function` declarations are block scoped?

Tags: javascript, scope, async-await

Should the following code work?

```
if(true) {
  async function bar() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
bar();
```

Chrome 80 and Firefox 72 both throw a `ReferenceError` saying `bar` is not defined. So it seems like `async function bar() {...}` declarations are block scoped whereas `function bar() {...}` declarations are function scoped? Confusing if that's the case, but can someone just confirm that for me with a link to the relevant part of the spec?

Also, is there a way to make an `async function` declaration function-scoped when declared from within a block?

Comment: I believe it behaves like `let` and `const`

Comment: Hmm. It behaves the same in node.js

Comment: I guess if you want to break out of block scope you can do it with: `var bar = async function () {}`

Comment: There doens't seem to be anything in the scope about this, @MysterX is probably right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems like `async function bar() {...}` declarations are block scoped

Yes, just like normal. Function declarations are block-scoped in general.

> … whereas `function bar() {...}` declarations are function scoped?

Not really, [except in sloppy mode for legacy reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461615/1048572). This does not affect `async function` and `function*` declarations, which don't need any backwards-compatibility.

Comment: You used the terms "like normal" and "in general" there to refer to strict-mode code, specifically, right? I.e. code in a ES6 module script or where `"use strict";` has explicitly been written at the top of the script or function?

Comment: @joe Yes, like in an ES6 module :-) Also I think there are some EcmaScript engines that don't implement Annex B at all.