# Evaling async function definitions

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, eval, definition

I work on an IDE for Javascript that lets
developers evaluate their code.
In a modern Chrome console, I can run:

```
eval(`try{function foo3(){console.log("Hi")}} catch(err){console.log(err)}`)
```

and foo3 will be defined and called fine.
I can also run:

```
eval(`async function foo4(){console.log("Hi")}`)
```

and foo4 will be defined and called fine.
But when I run:

```
eval(`try{async function foo5(){console.log("Hi")}} catch(err) {console.log(err)}`)
```

I get no error, but foo5 is not defined.
Note that the difference between example 1 and
example 3 is just "async" before "function".
I would like foo5 to be defined.
Clues greatly appreciated.

Comment: function declarations within blocks `{}` behave strangely due to web compatibility reasons and are often best avoided. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6) seems like it is also related

Comment: What is the point of the `try`/`catch`? You'll never get an exception only from defining a function.

Comment: Thanks Nick, it helps to realize this gray area of jS.

Comment: Bergi, the programmer might have typed in bad syntax for the function, so the outer try/catch can help catch that.

Comment: @user1343035 No, it doesn't. If the syntax is invalid, the entire statement doesn't get run. You'd need to place the `try` block around the `eval()` call to catch syntax errors.

Comment: @user1343035 And btw, it's not a gray area. If you `"use strict"` mode, you'll get the consistent modern behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could invert your code slightly, to include the `try/catch` block, within your `async` function to get it going.

```js
eval(`async function foo5() {try {console.log("Hi")} catch (err) { console.log(err)}}`);

foo5();
```

Comment: By the info the OP provided, I assume the "evaluator" in the IDE they are coding is something like this: `eval(\`try{ ${CUSTOM_CODE_HERE} } catch(err){console.log(err)}\`)`, So moving the target function outside of the `try` probably won't work (that's just how I understood it tho).

Comment: Well, [`eval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) just executes the string as if it were an actual piece of `javascript` code. So inverting the code, should work fine I feel.

Comment: NullDev, yes you have made a better description of my actual use case, thanks. Salvino I suspect you're right. Your answer was a quite clever "refactoring" of the problem. While not ideal, with a bit of work, it may well solve my problem.

Comment: Yep, please accept & upvote if you find this answer useful.