# Function being called even not in same scope?

Tags: javascript

I'm just getting back into coding and I'm curious as to why the `checkNum(oddNum)` function outside of the if statement is still being called?

If I'm understanding scoping correctly, shouldn't the `checkNum` function only be able to be called within the scope of the if statement?

Yes I am aware there is an easier way to do the check and the function is not required, but I am just practicing and trying to understand scoping. =D

```
let evenNum = 2; 
let oddNum = 3; 

if (evenNum < 5) {
    checkNum(evenNum);

    function checkNum(evenNum) {
        let isEven;
        isEven = evenNum % 2;
        if (isEven === 0) {
            console.log("The number is even");
        } else if (isEven != 0) { 
            console.log("The number is odd");
        } else {
            console.log("The number is greater than 5")
        }
    }
}

checkNum(oddNum);
```

EDIT:

As per javascript.info, this will not work, but the code seems to be similar?

```js
let age = 16; // take 16 as an example

if (age < 18) {
  welcome(); // \   (runs)
  //  |
  function welcome() {  //  |
    alert("Hello!");    //  |  Function Declaration is available
  }                     //  |  everywhere in the block where it's declared
                        //  |
  welcome(); // /   (runs)

} else {

  function welcome() {
    alert("Greetings!");
  }
}

// Here we're out of curly braces,
// so we can not see Function Declarations made inside of them.

welcome(); // Error: welcome is not defined
```

Comment: The `function` declaration is scoped to the function, not the block. Block scoping only happens for variables declared with `let` or `const`.

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect where my confusion lies.

Comment: I don't get an error with your second version.

Comment: You would only get an error if the function is defined in an `if` or `else` block that's never executed.

Comment: Weird. I get the error on the Javascript.info website after the first two function calls are executed, but it's not happening here.

From what I understand you're saying that Block Scope doesn't apply to function declarations, correct?

Comment: I haven't used javascript.info before. Do you have a link to the place where you can execute code?

Comment: Function declarations have block scope in strict mode, function scope in non-strict mode. So maybe javascript.info is using strict mode.

Comment: Another dupe target would be [what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6)

Comment: https://javascript.info/function-expressions

It's close to the bottom of the article near the summary @Barmar

Comment: javascript.info probably automatically has strict-mode.

Comment: From that page: **In strict mode, when a Function Declaration is within a code block, it’s visible everywhere inside that block. But not outside of it.**. Strict mode is not the default.