# Function declaration inside block scope overriding another function declaration

Tags: javascript, function

Can someone explain why first function is running not the second one when I call it?

```js
{
  function a() {
     console.log('first function')
  }
}

function a() {
     console.log('second function')
}

a()
```

If we declare them in a global scope they behave as expected, but inside block scope it's completely different. Why?

```js
function a() {
     console.log('first function')
}

function a() {
     console.log('second function')
}

a()
```

Comment: FWIW, it gives "second function" in both cases for me… macOS Safari…

Comment: This behavior is not consistent (node runs the second function for your first example, and throws an error for the second).

Comment: Functions aren't block scoped, so what exactly *is* the "expected behaviour"…?

Comment: @deceze es6 introduced block scoped functions see: [What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6) (also the reason the first example doesn't error in node as it doesn't see a conflict)

Comment: @pilchard *When* in strict mode, which doesn't doesn't appear to be…

Comment: True, but that is different than your blanket statement.

Answer (score 1):

The global function delaration move the function to top (hoisting), the one in the block stays at place.

The below result is from **Edge 103.0.1264.37**.

```js
a(); // second

{
  function a() {
     console.log('first function')
  }
}

a(); // first

function a() {
     console.log('second function')
}

a(); // first
```

Comment: This produces "second" three times in Safari…

Comment: @deceze, this is on Edge 103.0.1264.37.