# ECMAScript: FunctionDeclaration statement returning empty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Under ECMAScript's syntactic grammar for [function declarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-definitions), we have the [Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation) of function declarations.

It states that a *FunctionDeclaration* does not return anything (i.e. **empty**), and does not run any other code. Specifically, no new Declarative Environment Record (DER) is created, no function object is created, and no binding of an identifier to that function object occurs in the DER.

A *FunctionExpression*, on the other hand, runs [InstantiateOrdinaryFunctionExpression](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-instantiateordinaryfunctionexpression), which does the above (binding only happens if it's a named function expression).

If I write `function foo() {}` it seems to me that it will be interpreted as a *FunctionDeclaration*, and thus no binding will be made on any environment record. Which means, when I call the function `foo()` I get a *ReferenceError* ([Source](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getvalue))

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function *declarations* do declare the function for the whole scope. The function objects are created and the bindings are created and initialised when the **scope** is set up in [*FunctionDeclarationInstantiation*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) for function scopes, [*BlockDeclarationInstantiation*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-blockdeclarationinstantiation) for block scopes, [*InitializeEnvironment*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-source-text-module-record-initialize-environment) for module scopes, [*GlobalDeclarationInstantiation*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation) for global scopes etc.

When the statement is evaluated, it does indeed nothing<sup>1</sup>.

<sub>1: in strict mode, at least. In sloppy mode, there are [some legacy semantics for block-scoped function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461615/1048572).</sub>

Comment: Thank you, Bergi. I was thinking you would be the one to answer. The piece of the puzzle I am missing is where in the syntactic grammar we can see that `FunctionDeclarationInstantiation` is called. I searched for it in the spec, but it seems that function is only called when function bodies are evaluated: 15.2.3 Runtime Semantics: EvaluateFunctionBody (etc.). In other words, I want to follow the s. grammar and see that the instantiation happens. As noted in the OP, I can follow the grammar and see it for *FunctionExpression*, but not for *FunctionDeclaration*.

Comment: "*It seems that `FunctionDeclarationInstantiation` is only called when function bodies are evaluated*" - yes, it is: that's when the declared variables are created in the function scope! They're **hoisted**.

Comment: Indeed, I see in the grammar how the instantiation happens if a *FunctionDeclaration* appears inside a *FunctionBody* (i.e. in the *Function Execution Context*). However, a *FunctionDeclaration* might appear outside of a *FunctionBody*, for instance in the *Global Execution Context*. Do you know where in the grammar (in which Evaluation) the instantiation then begins?

Comment: @Magnus it's in `GlobalDeclarationInstantiation` then, as linked in my answer. (I think the only case I didn't link are `eval` scopes)

Comment: Ah, fantastic, it all came together now. Thank you! Just a quick algo question re. *GlobalDeclarationInstantiation*: There seems to be an overlap between *VarScopedDeclarations* and *LexicallyScopedDeclarations* (eg *FunctionDeclaration* is in both). Yet, it still creates bindings on the `Global Environment Record` for both (steps 15, 16, 17). Is it creating the same bindings multiple times?

Comment: Hmmm @Bergi, I see that most of the *VarScopedDeclarations* and *LexicallyScopedDeclarations* return empty lists (ie no Parse Nodes). In fact, it seems only *LexicallyScopedDeclarations* return a Parse Node for *FunctionDeclaration*. Am I understanding that right? If so, does it ever get a positive assertion in step `8.a.i` of  *GlobalDeclarationInstantiation*?

Comment: Posted this as a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74768923/ecmascript-is-varscopeddeclarations-not-returning-functiondeclaration