# The difference in behavior when calling the function in if(true) {}

Tags: javascript, function

This is the problem I see when browsing [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/task/function-in-if), the expected result should be an "error", as in the website.

[Related Links](https://javascript.info/closure#function-in-if)

```js
  let phrase = 'Hello';
  if(true) {
    let user = "John";

    function sayHi() {
      console.log(phrase, user);
    }
  }

  sayHi();
```

When I tried it, I found that both Chrome and Firefox output "Hello John" normally.
But the error in Safari is "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: user"

I don't know how to describe this behavior, so I can't find relevant information in the search engine. I hope someone can answer my doubts. Thank you!

Browser version:

- Chrome  110
- Firefox 109
- Safari  16.3

This question seems to be different from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6)

Comment: Related: [Function declarations inside if/else statements?](/q/10069204/4642212).

Comment: "*I don't know how to describe this behavior*" for Safari seems like the correct description would be "bug". Not that it's really much better in other browsers as web compatibility certainly has odd and unintuitive semantics.

Comment: javascript.info expects you to run in strict-mode, which you also should. There, it is an error. ["All examples in this tutorial assume strict mode unless (very rarely) specified otherwise."](https://javascript.info/strict-mode#should-we-use-strict) Perhaps they should have made that bold, red, and fontsize 48.