# Function declarations inside if/else statements?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

How are function declarations handled?

```js
var abc = '';
if (1 === 0) {
  function a() {
    abc = 7;
  }
} else if ('a' === 'a') {
  function a() {
    abc = 19;
  }
} else if ('foo' === 'bar') {
  function a() {
    abc = 'foo';
  }
}
a();
document.write(abc); //writes "foo" even though 'foo' !== 'bar'
```

This example produces different outputs in Chrome and Firefox. Chrome outputs `foo` while FF outputs `19`.

Comment: I get `19`. What engine are you using?

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mqs8Y/

Comment: @DC_: The link is giving me `19` in my console (firefox).

Comment: @jesse Odd, I get `foo` using Chrome.

Comment: So, SpiderMonkey works as expected, V8 works as per spec?

Comment: +1: Confirmed chrome and firefox produce different output.

Comment: All the engines work correctly here. Chrome et al. work directly via the spec, and FF's behaviour is an extension to the spec. I.e. it's different by design. Essentially (i.e. chrome) hoisting is performed and the last *declaration* wins, but FF implement what they call function statements (iirc the terminology), which allow for what would otherwise be declarations to be evaluated.

Comment: For further reference, check out the spec in section 12.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which JS function-declaration syntax is correct according to the standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758042/which-js-function-declaration-syntax-is-correct-according-to-the-standard)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

When this question was asked, ECMAScript 5 (ES5) was prevalent. In strict mode of ES5, function declarations cannot be nested inside of an `if` block as shown in the question. In non-strict mode, the results were unpredictable. Different browsers and engines implemented their own rules for how they would handle function declarations inside blocks.

As of 2018, many browsers support ECMAScript 2015 (ES2015) to the extent that [function declarations are now allowed inside blocks](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block). In an ES2015 environment, a function declaration inside of a block will be scoped inside that block. The code in the question will result in an undefined function error because the function `a` is only declared within the scope of `if` statements and therefore doesn't exist in the global scope.

If you need to conditionally define a function, then you should use [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Constructor_vs._declaration_vs._expression).

Comment: Finally, someone got it right. Well done! Probably worth mentioning who implements what (i.e. almost everyone goes by the ES recommendation save SpiderMonkey).

Comment: The statement that `the first example in the question is not legal syntax` is wrong, read davin's comment (which is spot on). Function statements are a legal extension to Mozilla's browsers.

Comment: @RobG: No, the answer is right, the first example is not legal as per the ECMAScript-262 Specification as only statements may appear in blocks and a function declaration is not a statement (extensions are not standard and not portable).

Comment: @Jesse—the specification allows extensions, Mozilla have chosen to allow a **FunctionStatement** (which is not described by ECMA-262) within a block. Therefore it is not an error, but a deliberate extenstion allowed by the specification. It is certainly not a syntax error and no UA that I know of throws an error when encountering it, they just process it differently depending on whether they see it as a FunctionDeclaration or FunctionStatement.

Comment: @RobG, fair enough, I'll be more specific.

Comment: I find this subject a very confusing one.  It seems like there isn't a concrete definition to what a function statement is.  The answer stated here states that "FunctionDeclaration is not a Statement" yet Douglas Crockford states that "if the first token in a statement is function, then it is a function statement."  I personally think we should do away with the terms function statements and function expressions and just call them functions.

Comment: strict mode sample is not working now. See [Conditionally created functions] :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function

Comment: @Tina, I need to update or delete this answer. ES2015 allows function declarations inside blocks.

Answer (score 7):

From http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

In javascript, you have function declaration:

```
function foo() {
}
```

and function expression

```
var foo = function() {
}
```

Quoting from http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

> “Function declarations and function variables are always moved
>   (‘hoisted’) to the top of their JavaScript scope by the JavaScript
>   interpreter”.

So what happened in your first example is that function declaration of `function a()`, gets hoisted to the top of the Javascript scope, thus producing 'foo' even though the if evaluates to false

Think of `var foo` as a normal Javascript statement, it's only executed on the runtime of your javascript, unlike `function foo()`, that's why the below is valid:

```
alert(foo());

function foo() {
   return 'gw ganteng';
}
```

Here, `function foo()` is parsed by the parser, putting `foo()` in the current scope, before attempting to call `alert(foo())`

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

> In JavaScript execution there is Context (which ECMA 5 breaks into
>   LexicalEnvironment, VariableEnvironment and ThisBinding) and Process
>   (a set of statements to be invoked in sequence). Declarations
>   contribute to the VariableEnvironment when the execution scope is
>   entered. They are distinct from Statements (such as return) and are
>   not subject to their rules of process.

Comment: Yes I think the key here is function vs expression.

Comment: Do you have any references that specify what the behavior *should* be?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams considering hoisting and execution flow, the *last* declaration should prevail.

Answer (score 2):

The ECMA-262 v5 requires implementations to register all function and variable declarations during the first pass when entering any new global or function-level execution context. Chrome is technically doing it right here because it is looking inside the `else` and `then` blocks and registering `a()` prior to execution. Unfortunately it produces the most unreadable results.

FF is waiting until it evaluates the if statement before it evaluates and adds function and variable declarations to the current context. BTW. Both browsers do it this way inside catch and finally clauses.

It really is just a matter of two different ECMA implementations dealing with a feature that shouldn't be there to begin with. The scenario at hand shows why function declarations shouldn't be inside control flow statements.

Answer (score 0):

#### Function declarations are not accessible outside `{}` blocks.

```
if (true) {
  function sayHi() {
    alert("hii");
  }
  sayHi(); //accessible
}

sayHi(); //error, not accessible since out of the block
```

#### If you want to define conditional functions, use function expressions like

```
let sayHi;
if (true) {
  sayHi = function(){
    alert("hii");
  }
  sayHi(); //accessible
}

sayHi(); //accessible
```

Comment: The code above does not produce error, it alerts 'hii' instead.
Chrome91

Comment: may be a browser enhancement?