# javascript: overriding (not just defining) a function in if statement

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript.

```
var f = function() { ... };
if (x === 1) {
    // redefine f.
    f = function() { 
       ...
    };
}
```

Is that code valid ? 
In other words can I redefine a javascript function inside an if statement where I actually write the code.

I am worried because of this:
[Function declarations inside if/else statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements)

Comment: @Kriem I think you are mistaken this is a different question. It concerns about hoisting and redefining and being in an if statemetn

Comment: I see that now. Apologies. I was too quick with my assumption.

Comment: @Kriem no worries... it happens... many thanks.

Comment: @Kriem can you take out the message "This question may already have an answer here" from the top... as we agree it's not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

```
f = function() { 
   ...
};
```

is **not** a function *declaration*, it is a function *expression* (assigned to `f`), so the problems mentioned in the other question don't apply here.

Only variable and function declarations are hoisted.

Comment: thanks very much would you mind elaborate your answer. I want to use this approach but I am still worried about how hoisting might affect this...

Comment: There is not much more to say. Only function and variables declarations are hoisted. The only declaration you have is `var f` at the beginning of your code. Assignments only take place when they are reached in the code.

Comment: yes but I define function f() again (inside the if) how do you know that that does not cause trouble ?

Comment: You are not defining a function `f` (you never did). You are assigning a value to the variable `f` which happens to be a function. Functions are first class objects in JavaScript, so it's the same as assigning any other value, e.g. `f = 42;`.

Comment: If you don't know about the differences between a function declaration and a function expression, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip.