# changing definition of js function not working in some browsers

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer

I searched for an answer to this but didn't find anything, although there must be a simple explanation.  The following function js shows different results in different browsers...could someone tell me why? many thanks

```
var i='a';

if (i=='a')  function theFunction(){alert('hi');}
else         function theFunction(){alert('bye');};

theFunction();

//ff results in hi
//ie results in bye
//chrome results in bye
```

Comment: That would be the missing curlybraces in the condition causing the issue.

Comment: And it alerts "bye" in all browsers for me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function declarations inside if/else statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use a function declaration inside an `if` block.

From [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf#page=98):

> NOTE  Several widely used implementations of ECMAScript are known to
>   support the use of *FunctionDeclaration* as a  *Statement*. However there
>   are significant and irreconcilable variations among the
>   implementations in the semantics applied  to such
>   *FunctionDeclarations*. Because of these irreconcilable differences, the
>   use of a *FunctionDeclaration* as a *Statement*  results in code that is
>   not reliably portable among implementations. It is recommended that
>   ECMAScript implementations  either disallow this usage of
>   *FunctionDeclaration* or issue a warning when such a usage is
>   encountered. Future editions of  ECMAScript may define alternative
>   portable means for declaring functions in a *Statement* context.

And if you try to use your code in strict mode, you get

```
SyntaxError: in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function
```

Instead, you can use

```
var i='a',
    theFunction;

if (i=='a')  theFunction = function(){alert('hi');}
else         theFunction = function(){alert('bye');};
theFunction();
```

Or, if your code is simple enough (like example above), use the ternary operator:

```
var theFunction = i=='a'
    ? function(){alert('hi');}
    : function(){alert('bye');};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a function from a condition expression:

```
var i='a';
var theFunction=(function(){
    if (i=='a')  return function theFunction(){alert('hi');}
    else return function theFunction(){alert('bye');};
})();

theFunction();
```

/* returns: 'hi' */

Answer (score 0):

I like a lot that pattern, so idiomatic, of a self-modifying function.
Its idea is to take advantage that a function declaration is a just a var declaration with an early evaluation (to say it in a few words) :

```
var seen=false;

function iWillSay() {
         if ( seen == false ) iWillSay = function() { alert('hi' );  };
         else                 iWillSay = function() { alert('bye');  };
         return iWillSay();
}

iWillSay();  // always says hi.
```