# Output is giving "1undefined" for something that should be "1function" for sure. Where is the Mistake?

Tags: javascript, html, function

The example below must output for sure function, as the value of x is "1" (integer) and then we are passing a parameter named "f" (of a function). It doesn't matter whether this function does something or is blank, but I am sure -- that variable f --> points to function. so `typeof(f)` will surely return `function`.

Now, adding of an integer and "function" (as typeof always returns a string) is going to be a string --> 1function.

Now, amazingly the output is "1undefined". How?

```html
<script>

var x = 1;
if (function f(){}) {
  x += typeof f;
}
console.log(x);

</script>
```

**As per answer by Ellepsis** that declarations don't take inside if() braces and only boolean is returned. Explain this then, why is it returning 3?

```html
<script>

var x = 1;
if (y = 2) {
x = x + y; 
}
console.log(x);

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> if (function f(){}) {
> ```

A function declaration will create a variable with the same name in the current scope.

A function expression will only create a variable with the same name inside itself.

So the variable `f` only exists:

```
if (function f(){    })
                 ^^^^
                 here
```

The function expression itself evaluates as a function, which the `if` statement picks up as a truthy value but there is no `f` variable in scope.

---

> Explain this then, why is it returning 3?

You are explicitly assigning a value to a variable. That variable remains in scope.

You would get the same effect if you did this:

```
if (f = function f(){}) {
```

---

So:

```
(function f(){})
```

- Creates a function
- Names the function `f`
- Creates a variable **inside** the function called `f` containing a reference to a function
- Evaluates as a function, which is a true value, which is tested by the `if`

While:

```
(f = function f(){})
```

- Creates a function
- Names the function `f`
- Creates a variable **inside** the function called `f` containing a reference to a function
- Creates a variable `f` outside the function
- `function f(){}` evaluates as a function and is assigned to `f` by the `=`
- `f = function f(){}` also evaluates as a function, which is a true value, which is tested by the `if`

Comment: So, the case comes different if we pass a variable referring to string, boolean, number, array, or undefined? like `y=3` or `z="peter"`? Then y & z exist in real world but not if we pass function `f`(){} --- I assume with same rules we already gave a name `f` to a function. Haven't we?

Comment: @Deadpool — Functions are not variables.

Comment: ok. Means assignment is power powerful and would logically make a variable exist than writing function `func(){}` --- meaning func never exists? I thought this is another way of creating a variable, say `func` which will point to memory location containing function data. isn't it?

Comment: "meaning func never exists" — The function exists.

Comment: "I thought this is another way of creating a variable, say func which will point to memory location containing function data." — JavaScript isn't assembly you don't deal directly with memory locations in it. I explained the difference between a function expression and a function declaration in the first section of this answer.

Comment: yah, I named my function func above! `function func(){}`

Comment: Why is `f` not hoisted here? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250601/hoisting-of-functions-inside-conditionals)

Comment: Function expressions are not hoisted (and since I already said they don't create a variable `f` in the outer scope … what would hoisting do anyway?!)

Comment: Got you. So, `if (function f(){})` is a function expression and not function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `undefined` because `function f` is not defined in the code anywhere. Writing the `function` inside an `if statement` does not define the `function`. The code just assumes it as a truthy value, a condition for the if statement but in real `f` does not exists. You can define `f` outside and it will work fine or you can just perform the assignment in the if and then also it will work

```js
var x = 1;
if (f=function(){}) {
  x += typeof f;
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: please see updated question. Your logic doesn't seem fit for all cases ... strangely!

Comment: In your second snippet you are assigning a value and then using it which is working. See the edits. When you assign a function it will work too. If you just define y in the if statement and not assign any value it will give error too. That is the difference between your two snippets

Answer (score -2):

```js
var x = 1;
var f;
if ( f = function() {} ) {
    x += typeof f;
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: I know that. But, just asking why in the given example the output is such; Not how can we bring in required result (that we want).