# Function in if condition clause

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, runtime-error

I have been given this function to predict the output.
  It's says refrence error,i am still wondering why?

```
  if(function x(){console.log("ABC");})
    {
      x();
    }
```

Hope somebody can throw some light on the lexical scope.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements

Comment: That's a function expression, and doesn't declare any variable in any scope but its own. You really really should not use that in the condition of an if statement.

Comment: @elclanrs: not exactly

Comment: Not exactly, you need to declare x first (or later due hoisting) to call it

Comment: function expressions execute immediately, and are scoped to their containing function block, in this case the parenthesis. x is undefined because its out of scope.

Comment: What is this supposed to do anyway? A function literal will always be *truthy*. What are you hoping to test there as condition?

Comment: like i said it's there to checkout lexical scope system in javascript , nothing to add to functionality as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there is a *function expression*, even if a *named* one, and you're not assigning that expression to anything. The fact that you're naming it `x` doesn't mean a function `x` will be hoisted in the scope, because that doesn't work for *expressions*.

```
function foo() {}    // function declaration
(function bar() {}); // named function expression, the () makes it not-a-statement here

foo();  // ok
bar();  // doesn't exist
```

So in effect you're never declaring a function `x`, which is why none exists when you try to call it.