# HTML speech not working on Safari mac "TypeError"

Tags: javascript, html, safari, text-to-speech

HTML5 speech is not working on Safari on a mac 10.0.1,

I get the error,

> TypeError: Argument 1 ('utterance') to SpeechSynthesis.speak must be
>   an instance of SpeechSynthesisUtterance

It works on Chrome and Firefox, and I'm pretty sure it used to work on Safari...

```
var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
u.text = "hello world";
u.lang = "en";
window.speechSynthesis.speak(u);
```

Comment: Hmm, odd. I just tested it on the same version Safari (10.0.1) and it worked fine.

Comment: This works for me as well on Safari 10.0.1 (11602.2.14.0.7) running on OS X 10.11.6. What versions of Safari are you seeing this error on? I am assuming an old version of Safari if you're running OS X 10.0.1?

Comment: the version is Safari 10.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally figured it out.

I had some compatibility code to support browser without html5 speech,

```
if (SpeechSynthesisUtterance == undefined) {
    function SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

This works on Chrome and Firefox, but on Safari it seems that any function in any script is evaluated when the script is parsed, so the function get declared even though SpeechSynthesisUtterance already exists.

Guess I'll need to do this differently...

Comment: You probably want: `if (!window.SpeechSynthesisUtterance) { window.SpeechSynthesisUtterance = function(text) { this.text = text; } }`, named functions in if statements are invalid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements