# In JavaScript, I don't understand the output of the code below

Tags: javascript, function

```js
var y = 1;
if (function f(){}) {
    y += typeof f;
}
console.log(y);
```

I expected that the output would be '1function'. However, the actual output is '1undefined'. As far as I know, function declaration is hoisted and inside if statement has access to the function f. But why it printed out undefined as if function has not been declared?

Comment: That is not a function declaration in the condition, it is a named function expression. The name of the function expression is available inside the function only, hence `f` in the example is not defined at all in the `if` block. If you tried to log `y`, you'd get an error.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements

Comment: Ah... a typo, should've been "If you tried to log `f` ..." ofcourse.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where have you found the snippet? Or are you just playing with JS?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare a function inside a condition. As soon as you put the function declaration outside, before the if statement, you can use it in the condition and the result will be as you expected:

```js
var y = 1;
function f(){}
  if (f) {
    y += typeof f;
  }
  console.log(y);
```

Edit: Well, turns out you actually CAN (sort of*), but not with the chosen notation. This will work:

```js
var y = 1, f;
  if (f = function(){}) {
    y += typeof f;
  }
  console.log(y);
```

* as Teemu noted in the comments, this is not really a function declaration, but rather an anonymous function a reference to which is assigned to the variable `f`.

Comment: In the second snippet there is also a function expression in the condition, this time it's anonymous, though. You really can't declare a function in a place where an expression is required.

Comment: Good catch - made an edit to explain this further. Better? :)

Comment: @downvoter: might care to go into detail?

Comment: Well, it is better, sort of ; ) Btw. I didn't vote your answer down.