# JQuery: using document.on inside if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, events

I have one .js file for the whole website, in some places in the code I put $(document).on event inside if condition to make the event only available in certain pages.

example:

```
if( $(".some-class").length )
{
    $(document).on("click",".some-button",function(){
    ......
    });
}
```

The code runs fine, but I am worried if this is bad practice? or if it will cause bugs on some older browsers?

I don't think there will be any benefit to performance from what I did, but if it is not harmful then I want to keep it, because it will be difficult to run over all the code to change it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you explain *why* you think this might be a bad practice or cause bugs on older browsers?

Comment: I read that it is bad to declare function inside if condition, because it will cause unpredictable behavior, I am not sure about that though

Comment: No it won't cause unpredictable behavior but at same time it doesn't seem you need to delegate it either if you are only concerned with existing elements

Comment: "I read that it is bad to declare function inside if condition, because it will cause unpredictable behavior..." Where did you read that?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements

Comment: That question doesn't apply here. You're creating an anonymous function, so there's no function hoisting and no reference to the function outside of the `if` statement.

Comment: BTW, I have no idea why this was closed as a duplicate of that particular question. It seems utterly unrelated.