# function declaration inside a block

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone so i ran into this problem

```js
function test() {
  test2();
  if (true) {
    function test2() {
      console.log(a);
    }
    let a = 4;
  }
}
```

I checked on the debugger to find out why it behaves the way it does
and I have seen that `test2` function got hoisted but it was set to `undefined`

My question is why? when a function isn't inside a block and I call it before the declaration it will work because of the creation phase so why in this case it doesn't?

Comment: [Function declarations inside if/else statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements)

Comment: Because you can't use  function if you declarated it in another  visibility area

Comment: @СергейПетрашко - It's more complicated than that. :-) In the OP's code, they could use `test2` *after* the `if` block, assuming they're in loose mode (there's no `"use strict"` above, but for all I know it's module code and already strict).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ,  I agree with you!. I was  writing  that  for give direction)

Comment: You are calling a function that does not exist yet. This is how works js. It's all about context and scope, line by line executed and the scope is populated.

Answer (score 2):

Function declarations inside blocks are different from function declarations at the top level of a scope, because...they're in a block. :-) They were only recently (ES2015) and partially standardized; prior to that, supporting them was an *allowed extension* to the specification, but unfortunately different JavaScript engines supported them slightly differently (and sometimes their support varied over time), so what got standardized had to be the intersection of things that behaved basically the same way across the various implementations.

Your example is one of those that behaved the same way, though, so we can say what the spec says about it. The function isn't assigned to the `test2` identifier until code execution enters the `if` block. Here's your code:

```js
function test() {
    test2();
    if (true) {
        function test2() {
          console.log(a);
        }
        let a = 4;
    }
}

test();
```

...and here's *roughly* how it's handled in loose mode (there's a very minor difference in strict mode):

```js
function test() {
    var test2; // Identifier declared and initialized with `undefined` here
    test2();
    if (true) {
        test2 = function test2() { // Function assigned here, at the top of the block
          console.log(a);
        };
        let a = 4;
    }
}

test();
```

As you can see, since the function hasn't been assigned to the `test2` var yet, you can't call it where you have the call.

It's not clear from your code, but the assignment to the `test2` identifier is hoisted to the top of the block where the function declaration appears. We can see that if we don't try to call it too early and log the value in `test2` prior to the block (where it's `undefined`) and inside the block above the declaration (where it's the function):

```js
function test() {
    console.log(test2);         // undefined
    // test2();
    if (true) {
        console.log(test2);     // the function - assignment was hoisted
        function test2() {
          console.log(a);
        }
        let a = 4;
    }
    console.log(test2);         // still available here!
}

test();
```

The slight difference in strict mode is primarily that the identifier has `let` semantics instead of `var` semantics and is only scoped to the block:

```js
"use strict";
function test() {
    // Can't use `test2` here at all
    if (true) {
        console.log(test2);     // Now it exists and has been initialized with the function
        function test2() {
          console.log(a);
        }
        let a = 4;
    }
    // Can't use `test2` here at all
}

test();
```

I always recommend using strict mode, and this is one of the reasons. To me, it just makes sense that a function declared within a block is only accessible within that block.

Comment: (FWIW, I go into the new standardized function declarations in blocks in detail in Chapter 3 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.)