# know the gender of name with javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Hello i am a beginner in JAVASCRIPT and i want to learn more about functions with parameters; i have problem in the second case the console write that sayhello it is not a function ( how can i fix this letter code please)

```js
var gender = prompt('are you mr or ms')
if (gender === 'mr') {
  function sayhello(name, gender) {
    return ('hello' + gender + name + ' how are you today')
  }
  console.log(sayhello(' mike', " mr "))
} else {
  console.log(sayhello(' emmy', " ms "))
}
```

Comment: declare `sayhello` outside the scope of the prompt. As far ar you can

Comment: You declared the `sayhello` function inside the `if` statement, so on the  `else` statement you will not have acces to the scope of the `sayhello` function.

Comment: In the old days this used to work (albeit very illogical). [But that is no longer the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your function `sayhello` outside [**if-else**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

When you define your function `sayhello` inside the `if` statement, you are limiting the scope of your function `sayhello`.

This means that, if any other part of your program wants to access the `sayhello` function, it won't be able to access it due to the limited accessibility of your function.

```js
var gender = prompt('are you mr or ms')
if (gender === 'mr') {
  console.log(sayhello(' mike', " mr "))
} else {
  console.log(sayhello(' emmy', " ms "))
}

function sayhello(name, gender) {
    return ('hello' + gender + name + ' how are you today')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is in the if statement.
I mean only if gender is equal to 'mr' you define a function.
Take your function up one level outside if and it will work.